# How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?

Tags: python, string, variables, string-interpolation

I would like to put an `int` into a `string`. This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
num = 40
plot.savefig('hanning40.pdf') #problem line
```

I have to run the program for several different numbers, so I'd like to do a loop. But inserting the variable like this doesn't work:

```
plot.savefig('hanning', num, '.pdf')
```

How do I insert a variable into a Python string?

---

#### See also

<sub>If you are trying to *create a file path*, see [How can I create a full path to a file from parts (e.g. path to the folder, name and extension)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132861) for additional techniques. It will usually be better to use code that is specific to creating paths.</sub>

<sub>If you are trying to *construct an URL with variable data*, **do not** use ordinary string formatting, because it is error-prone and more difficult than necessary. Specialized tools are available. See [Add params to given URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/).</sub>

<sub>If you are trying to *construct a SQL query*, **do not** use ordinary string formatting, because it is a **major security risk**. This is the cause of "SQL injection" which [costs real companies huge amounts of money every year](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sql+injection+annual+financial+impact). See for example [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408) for proper techniques.</sub>

<sub>If you *just want to `print` (output) the string*, you can prepare it this way first, **or** if you don't need the string for anything else, print each piece of the output individually using a single call to `print`. See [How can I print multiple things (fixed text and/or variable values) on the same line, all at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401) for details on both approaches.</sub>

<sub>See [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943) for bugs caused by trying to use `+` to join "strings" when one of them isn't a string.</sub>

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
plot.savefig('hanning(%d).pdf' % num)
```

The `%` operator, when following a string, allows you to insert values into that string via format codes (the `%d` in this case). For more details, see the Python documentation:

[`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: Note that the `%` operator is deprecated as of Python 3.1.  The new preferred way is to make use of the `.format()` method as discussed in [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) and mentioned in Dan McDougall's answer.

Comment: The `%` operator is not deprecated - it is just not the preferred way now.

Answer (score 827):

Using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
plot.savefig(f'hanning{num}.pdf')
```

This was added in 3.6 and is the new preferred way.

---

Using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
plot.savefig('hanning{0}.pdf'.format(num))
```

---

String concatenation:

```
plot.savefig('hanning' + str(num) + '.pdf')
```

---

[Conversion Specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
plot.savefig('hanning%s.pdf' % num)
```

---

Using local variable names (neat trick):

```
plot.savefig('hanning%(num)s.pdf' % locals())
```

---

Using [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template):

```
plot.savefig(string.Template('hanning${num}.pdf').substitute(locals()))
```

---

See also:

- [Fancier Output Formatting - The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)
- [Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide) - RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: To use the format string operator with multiple arguments, one can use a tuple as operand: `'foo %d, bar %d' % (foo, bar)`.

Comment: Your neat trick kind of works with the new format syntax too: `plot.savefig('hanning{num}s.pdf'.format(**locals()))`

Comment: had issues using locals () inside a function calling a global variable; used % globals() instead which worked

Comment: "There should be one -- _and preferably only one_ -- obvious way to do it.".

Comment: @MAChitgarha: Wishful thinking, but not something that could possibly hold for a language that's evolved over time.

Comment: f-strings are the preferred way *where possible*: i.e., when the formatting can be done immediately into a literal template. When it is necessary to save a template and reuse it, or postpone using it, f-strings do not work. In these cases, use the `.format` method.

Answer (score 213):

With [the introduction of formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) ("f-strings" for short) in Python 3.6, it is now possible to write this with a briefer syntax:

```
>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name}."
'He said his name is Fred.'
```

With the example given in the question, it would look like this

```
plot.savefig(f'hanning{num}.pdf')
```

Comment: It appears that [f-strings are compatible with multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023489/3357935).

Answer (score 20):

You can use `+` as the normal string concatenation function as well as `str()`.

```
"hello " + str(10) + " world" == "hello 10 world"
```

Comment: While this answer is correct building strings with `+` should be avoided as its extremely expensive

Comment: @slayton Also it's harder to read and write

Answer (score 7):

In general, you can create strings using:

```
stringExample = "someString " + str(someNumber)
print(stringExample)
plot.savefig(stringExample)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would want to put multiple values into the string you could make use of `format`

```
nums = [1,2,3]
plot.savefig('hanning{0}{1}{2}.pdf'.format(*nums))
```

Would result in the string `hanning123.pdf`. This can be done with any array.

Answer (score 5):

### Special cases

Depending on **why** variable data is being used with strings, the general-purpose approaches may not be appropriate.

#### If you need to prepare an SQL query

**Do not use** any of the usual techniques for assembling a string. Instead, use your SQL library's functionality for *parameterized* queries.

A query is **code**, so it should not be thought about like normal text. Using the library will make sure that any inserted text is properly escaped. If any part of the query could possibly come from outside the program in any way, that is an opportunity for a malevolent user to perform [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is widely considered one of the important computer security problems, costing real companies huge amounts of money every year and causing problems for countless customers. Even if you think you know the data is "safe", there is no real upside to using any other approach.

The syntax will depend on the library you are using and is outside the scope of this answer.

#### If you need to prepare a URL query string

See [Add params to given URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/). Do not do it yourself; there is no practical reason to make your life harder.

#### Writing to a file

While it's possible to prepare a string ahead of time, it may be simpler and more memory efficient to just write each piece of data with a separate `.write` call. Of course, non-strings will still need to be converted to string before writing, which may complicate the code. There is not a one-size-fits-all answer here, but choosing badly will generally not matter very much.

#### If you are simply calling `print`

The built-in `print` function accepts a variable number of arguments, and can take in any object and stringify it using `str`. Before trying string formatting, consider whether simply passing multiple arguments will do what you want. (You can also use the `sep` keyword argument to control spacing between the arguments.)

```
# display a filename, as an example
print('hanning', num, '.pdf', sep='')
```

Of course, there may be *other* reasons why it is useful for the program to assemble a string; so by all means do so where appropriate.

It's important to note that `print` is a special case. The only functions that work this way are ones that are explicitly written to work this way. For ordinary functions and methods, like `input`, or the `savefig` method of Matplotlib plots, we need to prepare a string ourselves.

### Concatenation

Python supports using `+` between two strings, [but not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943) between strings and other types. To work around this, we need to convert other values to string explicitly: `'hanning' + str(num) + '.pdf'`.

### Template-based approaches

Most ways to solve the problem involve having some kind of "template" string that includes "placeholders" that show where information should be added, and then using some function or method to add the missing information.

#### f-strings

This is the recommended approach when possible. It looks like `f'hanning{num}.pdf'`. The names of variables to insert appear directly in the string. It is important to note that *there is not actually such a thing as an "f-string"*; it's not a separate type. Instead, Python will translate the code ahead of time:

```
>>> def example(num):
...     return f'hanning{num}.pdf'
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(example)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hanning')
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('.pdf')
              8 BUILD_STRING             3
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Because it's a special syntax, it can access opcodes that aren't used in other approaches.

#### `str.format`

This is the recommended approach when f-strings aren't possible - mainly, because the template string needs to be prepared ahead of time and filled in later. It looks like `'hanning{}.pdf'.format(num)`, or `'hanning{num}.pdf'.format(num=num)'`. Here, `format` is a method built in to strings, which can accept arguments either by position or keyword.

Particularly for `str.format`, it's useful to know that the built-in `locals`, `globals` and `vars` functions return dictionaries that map variable names to the contents of those variables. Thus, rather than something like `'{a}{b}{c}'.format(a=a, b=b, c=c)`, we can use something like `'{a}{b}{c}'.format(**locals())`, [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/) the `locals()` dict.

#### `str.format_map`

This is a rare variation on `.format`. It looks like `'hanning{num}.pdf'.format_map({'num': num})`. Rather than accepting keyword arguments, it accepts a single argument which is a mapping.

That probably doesn't sound very useful - after all, rather than `'hanning{num}.pdf'.format_map(my_dict)`, we could just as easily write `'hanning{num}.pdf'.format(**my_dict)`. However, this is useful for mappings that determine values on the fly, rather than ordinary `dict`s. In these cases, unpacking with `**` might not work, because the set of keys might not be determined ahead of time; and trying to unpack keys based on the template is unwieldy (imagine: `'hanning{num}.pdf'.format(num=my_mapping[num])`, with a separate argument for each placeholder).

#### `string.Formatter`

The `string` standard library module contains a rarely used `Formatter` class. Using it looks like `string.Formatter().format('hanning{num}.pdf', num=num)`. The template string uses the same syntax again. This is obviously clunkier than just calling `.format` on the string; the motivation is to allow users to subclass `Formatter` to define a different syntax for the template string.

All of the above approaches use a common "formatting language" (although `string.Formatter` allows changing it); there are many other things that can be put inside the `{}`. Explaining how it works is beyond the scope of this answer; please [consult the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Do keep in mind that literal `{` and `}` characters need to be escaped by doubling them up. The syntax is presumably inspired by C#.

#### The `%` operator

This is a legacy way to solve the problem, inspired by C and C++. It has been discouraged for a long time, but is still supported. It looks like `'hanning%s.pdf' % num`, for simple cases. As you'd expect, literal `'%'` symbols in the template need to be doubled up to escape them.

It has some issues:

- It seems like the conversion specifier (the letter after the `%`) should match the type of whatever is being interpolated, but that's not actually the case. Instead, the value is converted to the specified type, and *then to string from there*. This isn't normally necessary; converting directly to string works most of the time, and converting to other types first doesn't help most of the rest of the time. So `'s'` is almost always used (unless you want the `repr` of the value, using `'r'`). Despite that, the conversion specifier is a mandatory part of the syntax.
- Tuples are handled specially: passing a tuple on the right-hand side is the way to provide multiple arguments. This is an ugly special case that's necessary because we aren't using function-call syntax. As a result, if you actually want to format a tuple into a single placeholder, it must be wrapped in a 1-tuple.
- Other sequence types are **not** handled specially, and the different behaviour can be a gotcha.

#### `string.Template`

The `string` standard library module contains a rarely used `Template` class. Instances provide `substitute` and `safe_substitute` methods that work similarly to the built-in `.format` (`safe_substitute` will leave placeholders intact rather than raising an exception when the arguments don't match). This should also be considered a legacy approach to the problem.

It looks like `string.Template('hanning$num.pdf').substitute(num=num)`, and is inspired by traditional Perl syntax. It's obviously clunkier than the `.format` approach, since a separate class has to be used before the method is available. Braces (`{}`) can be used optionally around the name of the variable, to avoid ambiguity. Similarly to the other methods, literal `'$'` in the template needs to be doubled up for escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for an extended version of this: instead of embedding a single number in a string, I needed to generate a series of file names of the form 'file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf' etc. This is how it worked:

```
['file' + str(i) + '.pdf' for i in range(1,4)]
```

Comment: The list comprehension is not relevant to OP's question, and the string formatting technique you're using is already covered in the [top answer](/a/2962966/4518341) and [goggin13's answer](/a/2960794/4518341). Please don't post answers that answer a different question or duplicate solutions. See [answer]. In any case, there's no reason to manually use `str()`; it's way easier to use f-strings for example: `f'file{i}.pdf'`

Answer (score -2):

You can make dict and substitute variables in your string.

```
var = {"name": "Abdul Jalil", "age": 22}
temp_string = "My name is %(name)s. I am %(age)s years old." % var
```