# How can I create a full path to a file from parts (e.g. path to the folder, name and extension)?

Tags: python, filenames

I need to pass a file path name to a module.  How do I build the file path from a directory name, base filename, and a file format string?

The directory may or may not exist at the time of call.

For example:

```
dir_name='/home/me/dev/my_reports'
base_filename='daily_report'
format = 'pdf'
```

I need to create a string `'/home/me/dev/my_reports/daily_report.pdf'`

Concatenating the pieces manually doesn't seem to be a good way. I tried `os.path.join`:

```
join(dir_name,base_filename,format)
```

but it gives

```
/home/me/dev/my_reports/daily_report/pdf
```

Comment: what's the problem with concatenating?

Answer (score 435, accepted):

This works fine:

```
os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename + '.' + filename_suffix)
```

Keep in mind that `os.path.join()` exists only because different operating systems use different path separator characters. It smooths over that difference so cross-platform code doesn't have to be cluttered with special cases for each OS. There is no need to do this for file name "extensions" (see footnote) because they are always preceded by a dot character, on every OS that implements them.

If using a function anyway makes you feel better (and you like needlessly complicating your code), you can do this:

```
os.path.join(dir_name, '.'.join((base_filename, filename_suffix)))
```

If you prefer to keep your code clean, simply include the dot in the suffix:

```
suffix = '.pdf'
os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename + suffix)
```

That approach also happens to be compatible with the suffix conventions in [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which was introduced in python 3.4 a few years after this question was asked. New code that doesn't require backward compatibility can do this:

```
suffix = '.pdf'
pathlib.PurePath(dir_name, base_filename + suffix)
```

You might be tempted to use the shorter `Path()` instead of `PurePath()` if you're only handling paths for the local OS. I would question that choice, given the cross-platform issues behind the original question.

Warning: Do not use pathlib's `with_suffix()` for this purpose. That method will corrupt `base_filename` if it ever contains a dot.

---

Footnote: Outside of Microsoft operating systems, there is no such thing as a file name "extension". Its presence on Windows comes from MS-DOS and FAT, which borrowed it from CP/M, which has been dead for decades. That dot-plus-three-letters that many of us are accustomed to seeing is just part of the file name on every other modern OS, where it has no built-in meaning.

Comment: You mentioned that the OS separator may not be `.`. For this one can use `os.extsep`.

Comment: I mentioned no such thing.

Comment: You went to some lengths to explain that 'File name "extensions" only have significant meaning on one major operating system (they're simply part of the file name on non-Windows systems), and their separator character is always a dot'. The OP also expressed they saw /pdf at the end. So you could have done `os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename, os.extsep, extension)`. Your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it gives back just a string so os.path.join(dir_name, ''.join([base_filename, os.extsep, extension])) should do it. Again, it doesn't undermine the correctness of your answer.

Comment: os.path.join is the best solution on python

Comment: @sjbx you should put `+` between filename parts. `os.path.join()` adds OS-specific path separators(`/` for example) between the arguments (as @sәɹoɈ correctly have them in his/her answer. Thus the correct form of your code snippet is: `os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename + os.extsep + extension)`

Comment: Not to be too bitchy, but don't all these example need a variable to store a result in?  As in:  foo = os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename).  That is not very clear with the posts.

Answer (score 74):

In Python 3.4 and above, the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) standard library module can be used like so:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> dirname, filename, suffix = '/home/reports', 'daily', '.pdf'
>>> Path(dirname, filename).with_suffix(suffix)
PosixPath('/home/reports/daily.pdf')
```

Comment: I find pathlib to be much more elegant than os.path.join, which seems pretty clunky by comparison.

Comment: Doesn't work if you filename has a "."
>>>filename2= 'daily.hourly'
>>>Path(dirname, filename2).with_suffix(suffix)
Output:WindowsPath('/home/reports/daily.pdf')

Comment: @wontleave: If a filename already has a suffix, [`with_suffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) will substitute it instead of appending. You want something like `Path(dirname, filename2 + suffix)`

Comment: `pathlib` also offers a clever operator overload: `(Path(dirname) / filename).with_suffix(suffix)`.

Answer (score 34):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename + "." + format)
'/home/me/dev/my_reports/daily_report.pdf'
```

Comment: thanks,but I was hoping there was a cleaner way of appending that extension..python even has a splitext function to cut off the extension..so there has to be something to do the reverse

Comment: The splitext function retains the '.' at the front of the extension.  This is likely the cleanest way to do it.  If you want it to "look" cleaner in your code, I'd suggest using a function or a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include the extension in the base filename?

```
dir_name='/home/me/dev/my_reports/'
base_filename='daily_report.pdf'
os.path.join(dir_name, base_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) (available from Version 3.6):

```
import os
path = '/my/folder'
name = 'report'
suffix = 'pdf'
os.path.join(path, f'{name}.{suffix}')
# Out: '/my/folder/report.pdf'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_PATH = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR,"templates")
print(TEMPLATE_PATH)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import os
def createfile(name, location, extension):
    print(name, extension, location)
    #starting creating a file with some dummy contents
    path = os.path.join(location, name + '.' + extension)
    f = open(path, "a")
    f.write("Your contents!! or whatever you want to put inside this file.")
    f.close()
    print("File creation is successful!!")

def readfile(name, location, extension):
    #open and read the file after the appending:
    path = os.path.join(location, name + '.' + extension)
    f = open(path, "r")
    print(f.read())

#pass the parameters here
createfile('test','./','txt')
readfile('test','./','txt')
```