# how to open a folder of images (Python)

Tags: python, image, directory

I'm working on a program to open a folder full of images, copy the images, and then save the copies of the images in a different directory.

I am using Python 2.4.4, but I am open to upgrading the program to a newer version if that allows me to import PIL or Image because I cannot do that with my version.

As of now, I have:

```
import Image
import os

def attempt():
    path1 = "5-1-15 upload"
    path2 = "test"

    listing = os.listdir(path1)
    for image in listing:
        im = Image.open(path1)
        im.save(os.path.join(path2))
```

I am new to Python, so this is probably obviously wrong for numerous reasons.

I mostly need help with opening a folder of images and iterating through the pictures in order to save them somewhere else.

Thanks!

**Edit**- I've tried this now:

```
import shutil

def change():
    shutil.copy2("5-1-15 upload", "test")
```

And I am receiving an IOError now: IOError: System.IO.IOException: Access to the path '5-1-15 upload' is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '5-1-15 upload' is denied.

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0

Am I entering the folders wrong? How should I do this if it an a folder within a specific computer network.

Basically there is a folder called images with multiple subfolders within it which I am trying to extract the images from.

Comment: If you don't have to alter the images, you can just copy the files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: It would probably be easiest to do this in your system's command/shell/terminal.

Comment: Just curious: how/why are you using Python 2.4.4? That is soooo old.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It's just what I already had downloaded and what my professor taught us on

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyway. You said you know how to do this with files. So do that. Image files *are* files. You don't need to treat them any differently.

Comment: You should really be using 2.7 at the very least, or the latest version of Python 3 if possible. Versions older than 2.7 are not maintained/supported (2.4.4 was released _in 2006_), and [all new development is focused on 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks, just downloaded 3.1

Comment: Why not 3.4.3, if I may ask?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was downloading it through Calico, so that wasn't an option

Comment: Try the [official site](https://www.python.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123226/3501291), copyfile will do the trick, as you are just copying images from one side to another, as if it was another type of file.

```
import shutil
import os

def attempt():
    path1 = "5-1-15 upload"
    path2 = "test"

    listing = os.listdir(path1)
    for image in listing:
        copyfile(image, path2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but i'm getting an error that says global name copyfile not found. This doesn't make sense though because I already imported it, right?

Comment: I tried shutil.copyfile but i'm receiving a different directory error with that not being able to find the file

Comment: @AlinaDW, this is because you probably need to include the full path. Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132861/building-full-path-filename-in-python