# How to append files names with the path in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have path variable path = 'C:\Users\Sony\Desktop', now I am finding all the text files in this directory and saving their names in a list by this code :

```
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
print text_files
```

This will give me ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'k.txt', 'link.txt']

Now I want to open these files one by one to find a word , for tht I need full

```
url=["C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\a.txt","C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.txt","C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\k.txt","C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\link.txt"]
```

how to append path with the file name , when I do url=path+'\'+text_files[0] then I get error , '\' is taken as escape, plz help

Comment: Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: Alternatively, use `glob.glob("{}\\*.txt".format(path))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a full path to a file from parts (e.g. path to the folder, name and extension)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132861/how-can-i-create-a-full-path-to-a-file-from-parts-e-g-path-to-the-folder-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to escape the backslash since it is a special character.
`url=path+'\\'+text_files[0]`

Read more about escape sequences [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

However, if portability of your Python script (across OSs) is important for you then use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: Thanks, I did this only ! Can u help me with another prob plz

Comment: If it is unrelated, then raise another question; otherwise mention it here in the comments section itself.

Comment: I am not able to post it as it takes after every 90 minutes

Comment: I have a list of paths of my text files :-['C:\\Users\\Sony\\Desktop\\a.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Sony\\Desktop\\b.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Sony\\Desktop\\k.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Sony\\Desktop\\link.txt']  now I want to find whether a word "What" is in these or not ?

Comment: I have used this code :-

    for items in url:
           page = open(items,'r')
           soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
           searched_word = 'What'
           results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
           print len(results)

Comment: now len(results) will give the number of times this word has occured in a particular text file, Now the problem is that when the word is not found in the any of the list of files then I get error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\MetaSearchEngine\pathfind.py", line 30, in <module>
    results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Actually I am saving html files as .txt files in my local directory and then when I try to get the list of .txt files from that location then It is giving me all txt files and not those original html files converted to txt

Comment: link.txt was not an html file originally so it is giving me error

Comment: I haven't used BeautifulSoup but it looks like `soup.body` is `None`. It is for you to find out why that is so but until then first check the validity of the object before using findall(), i.e. `If soup.body: soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)`.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `text_files = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in text_files]`

You can find more on the path module here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: for items in text_files:
    print items
    page = open(items,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
    searched_word = 'What'
    results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
    print len(results)

Comment: I get exception when the word "What" is not in one of the webpages  "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\MetaSearchEngine\pathfind.py", line 30, in <module>
    results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'