# How do I create a multiline Python string with inline variables?

Tags: python, string, variables, multiline

I am looking for a clean way to use variables within a multiline Python string. Say I wanted to do the following:

```
string1 = go
string2 = now
string3 = great

"""
I will $string1 there
I will go $string2
$string3
"""
```

I'm looking to see if there is something similar to `$` in Perl to indicate a variable in the Python syntax.

If not - what is the cleanest way to create a multiline string with variables?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The common way is the `format()` function:

```
>>> s = "This is an {example} with {vars}".format(vars="variables", example="example")
>>> s
'This is an example with variables'
```

It works fine with a multi-line format string:

```
>>> s = '''\
... This is a {length} example.
... Here is a {ordinal} line.\
... '''.format(length='multi-line', ordinal='second')
>>> print(s)
This is a multi-line example.
Here is a second line.
```

You can also pass a dictionary with variables:

```
>>> d = { 'vars': "variables", 'example': "example" }
>>> s = "This is an {example} with {vars}"
>>> s.format(**d)
'This is an example with variables'
```

The closest thing to what you asked (in terms of syntax) are [template strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings). For example:

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> t = Template("This is an $example with $vars")
>>> t.substitute({ 'example': "example", 'vars': "variables"})
'This is an example with variables'
```

I should add though that the `format()` function is more common because it's readily available and it does not require an import line.

Comment: Could use `vars()` or `locals()` as the dictionary in question

Comment: @isbadawi Explicit is better than implicit. Better to pass in only the variables you need. If you don't know which you need, because the string is supplied by the user, the "variables" should be items in a `dict` anyway.

Comment: The second solution is cleanest IMO. The dictionary along with clear variable name from the dictionary within the multiline sting. I will be using this method. Thanks. Loads of great answers below too but this was perfect.

Comment: @SimeonVisser, "string".format(...) is not valid on legacy python versions (e.g. 2.4)

Comment: If using curly braces, they need to be escaped like `{{this}}`.

Comment: i'm trying to substitue value of Y in below codeusing format function raw_data ="""query getSpace {
  space(id: {y}) {
    title
    description

    membersUpdated
    members {
      items {
        email
        displayName
      }
    }
    conversation{
      messages{
        items {
          content
        }
      }
    }
  }
}""".format(y='5bfe4e1e653c890001871844')  But i'm getting Error: Please help

Comment: The `'''string here'''` technique is a solid technique, and works well, but it creates some REALLY UGLY source code when you have to left-align all but the first line and your source code is indented several levels. To get pretty and easy-to-look-at source code with nice alignment, therefore, use this technique here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564926/4561887. It has its drawbacks, of course, but for anything less than a long paragraph of text, I like this other technique over using the `''' '''` technique.

Answer (score 81):

You can use [Python 3.6's f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205190/3357935) for variables inside [multi-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10660435/3357935) or lengthy single-line strings. You can manually specify newline characters using `\n`.

## Variables in a multi-line string

```
string1 = "go"
string2 = "now"
string3 = "great"

multiline_string = (f"I will {string1} there\n"
                    f"I will go {string2}.\n"
                    f"{string3}.")

print(multiline_string)
```

> I will go there
>   I will go now
>   great

## Variables in a lengthy single-line string

```
string1 = "go"
string2 = "now"
string3 = "great"

singleline_string = (f"I will {string1} there. "
                     f"I will go {string2}. "
                     f"{string3}.")

print(singleline_string)
```

> I will go there. I will go now. great.

---

Alternatively, you can also create a multiline f-string with triple quotes.

```
multiline_string = f"""I will {string1} there.
I will go {string2}.
{string3}."""
```

Comment: This keeps your source code looking pretty, and in pre-Python3.6 you can get the same effect just by doing this (extra set of parenthesis and using `+` to concatenate): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564926/4561887

Comment: Triple quoting is *vastly* preferred. You should present that form first.

Comment: @jpmc26 I presented parenthesis-style first based on [PEP 8's guidelines for code indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). Why would triple quoting be preferred?

Comment: I always forget about the `f` prefix to enable formatting inline. But I like this approach for multi-inline formatting.

Answer (score 72):

**NOTE**: The recommended way to do string formatting in Python is to use `format()`, as outlined in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10112665/815632). I'm preserving this answer as an example of the C-style syntax that's also supported.

```
# NOTE: format() is a better choice!
string1 = "go"
string2 = "now"
string3 = "great"

s = """
I will %s there
I will go %s
%s
""" % (string1, string2, string3)

print(s)
```

Some reading:

- [String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting)
- [PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: This isn't really the same because the OP wants named parameters, not positional ones.

Comment: It's still a good solution, and for a multi-line interpolation it's more direct. You don't have to import anything and it uses regular python interpolation.

Comment: "*You probably could have answered this one with a little bit of Googling*" Implying that we didn't find this post after Googling...

Comment: +1 because your solution is the simplest method of interpolating variables into a string which contains many curly braces unrelated to the variables being interpolated!

Answer (score 31):

**f-strings**, also called “formatted string literals,” are string literals that have an `f` at the beginning; and curly braces containing expressions that will be replaced with their values.

f-strings are evaluated at runtime.

So your code can be re-written as:

```
string1="go"
string2="now"
string3="great"
print(f"""
I will {string1} there
I will go {string2}
{string3}
""")
```

And this will evaluate to:

```
I will go there
I will go now
great
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#triple-quoted-f-strings).

Answer (score 14):

This is what you want:

```
>>> string1 = "go"
>>> string2 = "now"
>>> string3 = "great"
>>> mystring = """
... I will {string1} there
... I will go {string2}
... {string3}
... """
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'string3': 'great', '__package__': None, 'mystring': "\nI will {string1} there\nI will go {string2}\n{string3}\n", '__name__': '__main__', 'string2': 'now', '__doc__': None, 'string1': 'go'}
>>> print(mystring.format(**locals()))

I will go there
I will go now
great
```

Comment: Note that triple quotes `"""` preserves newlines, which means there is an extra newline before and after `mystring`

Comment: You can use ``.strip()``, ``.rstrip()`` or ``.lstrip()``, or ue a backlash inside the triple quotes to avoid creating a newline. 

mystring = """\
ABC\
"""

Answer (score 13):

If anyone came here from python-graphql client looking for a solution to pass an object as variable here's what I used:

```
query = """
{{
  pairs(block: {block} first: 200, orderBy: trackedReserveETH, orderDirection: desc) {{
    id
    txCount
    reserveUSD
    trackedReserveETH
    volumeUSD
  }}
}}
""".format(block=''.join(['{number: ', str(block), '}']))

 query = gql(query)
```

Make sure to escape all curly braces like I did: "{{", "}}"

Comment: Useful example for GraphQL highlighting how to escape braces. For simpler interpolation, query = f""" {{ pairs( block: {block_value} ...) {{ ... }} }} """ also works.

Answer (score 8):

A dictionary can be passed to [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), each key name will become a variable for each associated value.

```
dict = {'string1': 'go',
        'string2': 'now',
        'string3': 'great'}

multiline_string = '''I'm will {string1} there
I will go {string2}
{string3}'''.format(**dict)

print(multiline_string)
```

Also a list can be passed to [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), the index number of each value will be used as variables in this case.

```
list = ['go',
        'now',
        'great']

multiline_string = '''I'm will {0} there
I will go {1}
{2}'''.format(*list)

print(multiline_string)
```

Both solutions above will output the same:

> I'm will go there
>   I will go now
>   great

Answer (score 2):

```
print (f" \
      What you want to write {var_one} \n \
      What you want to write {var_two} \n \
      What you want to write {var_three} \n \
      Et cetera {var_four}")
```

This was what was working for me. Maybe it helps someone, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to use f-string multiline.

```
string1 = "go"
string2 = "now"
string3 = "great"

s = f"""
I will {string1} there
I will go {string2}
{string3}
"""

print(s)
```

This will return.

```
I will go there
I will go now
great
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to break a string into multiple lines in a @dataclass for use with QT style sheets. The end of each line needs to be terminate in double quote followed by a slash, except for the last line. Indentation of the start of each line is also critical.

```
@dataclass

class button_a:

   i: str = "QPushButton:hover {background: qradialgradient(cx:0, cy:0, radius:1,fx:0.5,fy:0.5,stop:0 white, stop:1 green);"\

   "color:qradialgradient(cx:0, cy:0, radius:1,fx:0.5,fy:0.5,stop:0 yellow, stop:1 brown);"\

   "border-color: purple;}"
```