# Multi-line string with extra space (preserved indentation)

Tags: string, bash, shell, echo

I want to write some pre-defined texts to a file with the following:

```
text="this is line one\n
this is line two\n
this is line three"

echo -e $text > filename
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
```

But got this:

```
this is line one
 this is line two
 this is line three
```

I'm positive that there is no space after each `\n`, but how does the extra space come out?

Comment: I'm not sure but.. how if you just typed `text="this is line one\nthis is line two\nthis is line three"` in the same one line..? (without any enter)

Comment: Remove the `\n` on each line, you have already hit newline to move to the new line

Comment: You already given `\n`.So why you put next line in new line? Simply `text="this is line one\nthis is line two\nthis is line three"`

Comment: Removing the `\n` at the end of each line causes the output to all run together on a single line.

Comment: Aha: Putting double quotes around the `"$text"` in the echo line is crucial. Without them, none of the newlines (both literal and '\n') work. With them, they all do.

Comment: Always quote your bash variables. ALWAYS... unless you know why it should not be quoted.

Comment: There is a white space after your \n characters I guess that's the reason you get that output. Try to delete these whitespaces.

Comment: With a great-deal of effort, study, and experimenting over the last couple of years, I was able to write what I consider to be a very [clean-looking, easy-to-read, almost "Pythonic" answer that I am very proud of here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71169983/4561887), and which also answers your question of `but how does the extra space come out?` (this may be the only answer that does that).

Comment: See also: [How to output a multiline string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10969953/4561887)

Answer (score 1036, accepted):

Heredoc sounds more convenient for this purpose. It is used to send multiple commands to a command interpreter program like *ex* or *cat*

```
cat << EndOfMessage
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
EndOfMessage
```

The string after `<<` indicates where to stop.

To send these lines to a file, use:

```
cat > $FILE <<- EOM
Line 1.
Line 2.
EOM
```

You could also store these lines to a variable:

```
read -r -d '' VAR << EOM
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
EOM
```

This stores the lines to the variable named `VAR`.

When printing, remember the quotes around the variable otherwise you won't see the newline characters.

```
echo "$VAR"
```

Even better, you can use indentation to make it stand out more in your code. This time just add a `-` after `<<` to stop the tabs from appearing.

```
read -r -d '' VAR <<- EOM
    This is line 1.
    This is line 2.
    Line 3.
EOM
```

But then you must use tabs, not spaces, for indentation in your code.

Comment: why do you have <<- instead of << on the first line of the 2nd and 5th code block? does - do anything special?

Comment: @sup3rman Tested with and without the "-" after "<<" and both worked normally in Debian 8.1

Comment: @sup3rman '-' Ignores leading tabs.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash

Comment: how can I make read exit with status 0? It seems like it can't find end of line (since it's -d '') and exits with 1 which doesn't help when you are in script.

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev use -d '\0' and add a \0 at the end of your last line

Comment: Using the `-d` option in `read -r -d '' VARIABLE <<- EOM` did not work for me.

Comment: @LarsSchneider: Thanks for the tip. Could you help me understand why substituting empty string with \0 solves the problem?

Comment: @trinth \0 is explicit "end marker" whereas an empty string is not I think.

Comment: "`It is used to send multiple commands to a command interpreter program like ex or cat`" How is `cat` a command interpreter program?

Comment: It's worth noting that bash variables are substituted between EOMs. Use `\$` to print verbatim.

Comment: I get the error message `ambiguous redirect` when I'm using 
`cat > $FILE <<- EOM...EOM`.
Does someone know why?

Comment: how do i iterate through the VAR line by line?

Comment: @dron22 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501480/why-bash-stops-with-parameter-e-set-e-when-it-meets-read-command

Comment: Be careful when using bash's `set -e`: read returns 1 (error) in this case (didn't find `''`), so rather use `read -r -d '' VAR << EOM || :`.
See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265164/288001

Comment: This still does not solve the indentation problem as the end EOM must be first on the line, thus NOT indented. How would you use this inside an indented IF-statement for example?

Comment: If you are looking to append multiple lines to a file, simply change `cat >` to `cat >>`

Comment: for me this is one of the best answers in stackoverflow

Comment: Why does "$VAR" preserve new lines when $VAR does not?

Comment: `read -d` isn't POSIX compliant, however `usage="$(cat << EOF ...` will work fine on any shell.

Answer (score 374):

If you're trying to get the string into a variable, another easy way is something like this:

```
USAGE=$(cat <<-END
    This is line one.
    This is line two.
    This is line three.
END

)
```

If you indent your string with tabs (i.e., '\t'), the indentation will be stripped out.  If you indent with spaces, the indentation will be left in.

NOTES:

- It *is* significant that the last closing parenthesis is on another line.  The `END` text must appear on a line by itself.
- When using this variable, to preserve non-readable chars (`\t`, `\n`) you must quote it. I.e. use `echo "$USAGE"` (not: `echo $USAGE`)

Comment: Is is that significant? Works on my mac with `)` on the same line. I think it's because what goes between `$(` and `)` is gonna execute in its own universe, and the actual command won't see ')' anyway. I wonder if it works for others too.

Comment: It's possible that different shells will interpret things differently.  In the [bash documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) it doesn't seem to say anything one way or the other, but all the examples have it on its own line.

Comment: Fun thing is, I found you answer when trying to set value for USAGE variable too. So your answer matches exactly. :)

Comment: @deej From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04): _The here-document … continues until there is a line containing only the delimiter and a <newline>_

Comment: @Fornost It does not contradict what I said

Comment: You say that the actual command won't see ')', and I agree. However, the actual command will see if there is a newline or no newline after END. Bash gives me a warning: _here-document delimited by end-of-file_.

Comment: @Fornost typically that means you have a space instead of a tab if you are using the `<<-END` style. Run `shellcheck` against your script to see if it spots any issues.

Comment: It's important to note the difference between `echo $USAGE` vs `echo "$USAGE"` when using this.

Comment: Both I and others on this thread have successfully used this approach on the Mac when using the `bash` shell.  I suspect your problem may be that newer Macs don't use the `bash` shell by default anymore (they use `zsh`), and the syntax may be different on that shell.

Comment: It's good but unfortunately removes comma from string within it

Comment: I happen to write sql inside this. Tuns out that if you write * inside it will expand the file system. Select * from table turned into select dir1, dir2, dir3 from table.

Comment: For some reason by bash (either bash or tcsh) shows all the lines appended. EDIT: Ok, remember to print it with echo "$USAGE"

Comment: As the END needs to be first on a line of it's own, it kind of defeats the whole purpose. Then you cant indent the whole statement, like inside an IF statement.

Comment: This broke the syntax highlighting of my text editor

Comment: @Kashyap Thanks! Your comment helped solve my issue. My next question - why does the output vary between the two commands?

Comment: @JohnC, without quote shell interprets (gobbles up) the non-readable chars in string and passes result to echo, with quotes, it passes string as-is to `echo`. Same reason why `echo -e "a\nb"` vs `echo -e a\nb`.

Answer (score 129):

`echo` adds spaces between the arguments passed to it. `$text` is subject to variable expansion and word splitting, so your `echo` command is equivalent to:

```
echo -e "this" "is" "line" "one\n" "this" "is" "line" "two\n"  ...
```

You can see that a space will be added before "this". You can either remove the newline characters, and quote `$text` to preserve the newlines:

```
text="this is line one
this is line two
this is line three"

echo "$text" > filename
```

Or you could use `printf`, which is more robust and portable than `echo`:

```
printf "%s\n" "this is line one" "this is line two" "this is line three" > filename
```

In `bash`, which supports brace expansion, you could even do:

```
printf "%s\n" "this is line "{one,two,three} > filename
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why mod sees extra space when using “echo” command. This answer also is working well when using in bash script (as oppose to interactive shell session). Feel like this is the real answer and should be an accepted answer.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. All other answers provided tons of interesting *other* ways to solve OP's pain, but technically the question was "how does the extra space come out" and no one addressed this :-) !!!  Thank you, Josh for making -1 mystery!

Answer (score 72):

in a bash script the following works:

```
#!/bin/sh

text="this is line one\nthis is line two\nthis is line three"
echo -e $text > filename
```

**alternatively:**

```
text="this is line one
this is line two
this is line three"
echo "$text" > filename
```

cat filename gives:

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
```

Comment: It seems the alternative trick works while Shell Scripts but it does not seem to work for bash.

Comment: @Macindows I seem to have forgotten the `-e` option for `echo`. Please try again.

Answer (score 49):

I've found more solutions since I wanted to have every line properly indented:

1. You may use `echo`:

   ```
   echo    "this is line one"   \
       "\n""this is line two"   \
       "\n""this is line three" \
       > filename
   ```

   It does not work if you put `"\n"` just before `\` on the end of a line.
2. Alternatively, you can use `printf` for better portability (I happened to have a lot of problems with `echo`):

   ```
   printf '%s\n' \
       "this is line one"   \
       "this is line two"   \
       "this is line three" \
       > filename
   ```
3. Yet another solution might be:

   ```
   text=''
   text="${text}this is line one\n"
   text="${text}this is line two\n"
   text="${text}this is line three\n"
   printf "%b" "$text" > filename
   ```

   or

   ```
   text=''
   text+="this is line one\n"
   text+="this is line two\n"
   text+="this is line three\n"
   printf "%b" "$text" > filename
   ```
4. Another solution is achieved by  mixing `printf` and `sed`.

   ```
   if something
   then
       printf '%s' '
       this is line one
       this is line two
       this is line three
       ' | sed '1d;$d;s/^    //g'
   fi
   ```

   It is not easy to refactor code formatted like this as you hardcode the indentation level into the code.
5. It is possible to use a helper function and some variable substitution tricks:

   ```
   unset text
   _() { text="${text}${text+
   }${*}"; }
   # That's an empty line which demonstrates the reasoning behind 
   # the usage of "+" instead of ":+" in the variable substitution 
   # above.
   _ ""
   _ "this is line one"
   _ "this is line two"
   _ "this is line three"
   unset -f _
   printf '%s' "$text"
   ```

Comment: 3b is my preferred solution when wanting to preserve code indentation and string indentation independently, at least when I cannot use 2 in variable assignment, and is more readable than 3a.  When I don't care I just keep the quoted string open over the several lines.

Comment: Very nice answer especially 3b

Comment: "It does not work if you put "\n" just before \ on the end of a line." - is a **great tip** when using echo.

Comment: printf saved me in a bare-bones docker container and no need for \n was really nice

Answer (score 16):

The following is my preferred way to assign a multi-line string to a variable (I think it looks nice).

```
read -r -d '' my_variable << \
_______________________________________________________________________________

String1
String2
String3
...
StringN
_______________________________________________________________________________
```

The number of underscores is the same (here 80) in both cases.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

### Hard to read:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930212/4561887) looks way too bash-like :) (hard to read) for my general taste:

```sh
cat << EndOfMessage
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
EndOfMessage
```

### Better, easier-to-read:

Let's get something a little more Pythonic (this is still bash):

```sh
text="this is line one
      this is line two
      this is line three\n"
dedent text
printf "$text"             # print to screen
printf "$text" > file.txt  # print to a file
```

Ah...that's better. :) It reminds me of Python's [`textwrap.dedent()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) function [which I use here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64437283/4561887).

Here is what the magic `dedent` function looks like:

```sh
dedent() {
    local -n reference="$1"
    reference="$(echo "$reference" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//')"
}
```

Sample output to screen:

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
```

WithOUT calling `dedent text` first`, the output would look like this:

```
this is line one
      this is line two
      this is line three
```

The variable `text` is passed to `dedent` *by reference*, so that what is modified **inside** the function affects the variable **outside** the function.

For more details and explanation and references, see my other answer here: [Equivalent of python's textwrap dedent in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71169678/4561887)

### Problem with your original attempt

OP's quote (with my emphasis added):

> I'm positive that there is no space after each `\n`, but **how does the extra space come out?**

Your original attempt was this:

```sh
text="this is line one\n
this is line two\n
this is line three"
echo -e $text
```

...but your output had an extra space before the 2nd and 3rd line. Why?

By deduction and experimentation, my conclusion is that `echo` converts the actual newline at the end of the line (the one you got when you actually pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>) *into a space*. That space therefore shows up before the line just *after* each `\n` in the text.

So, the solution is to escape the real newline at the end of each line by putting a backslash `\` at the end of any line within the quotes of your string, like this:

```sh
text="this is line one\n\
this is line two\n\
this is line three"

echo -e "$text"
```

Do NOT put a space *before* those trailing backslashes (like this: `text="this is line one\n \`) or that space will go right back into your output and cause you the same problem with the extra space!

OR, just use my technique with the `dedent` function above, which also has the added functionality of being able to indent with your code to look really pretty and nice and readable.

Answer (score 7):

I came hear looking for this answer but also wanted to pipe it to another command.  The given answer is correct but if anyone wants to pipe it, you need to pipe it before the multi-line string like this

```
echo | tee /tmp/pipetest << EndOfMessage
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
EndOfMessage
```

This will allow you to have a multi line string but also put it in the stdin of a subsequent command.

Answer (score 3):

As per [@alphado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930212/381083), and subsequent comments, this is what worked for me and gives **0 exit status**.

```
read -r -d '\0' VAR <<- EOM
    This is line 1.
    This is line 2.
    Line 3.
\0
EOM
```

- `<<-` to ignore leading tabs
- set `\0` as explicit "end marker"
- this also substitutes variables between the EOMs, so use `\$` to print verbatim.

*(Just putting this as a separate answer because it got hard to decipher this between all the comments, and did not want to change too much in original answer)*

Answer (score 2):

it will work if you put it as below:

```
AA='first line
\nsecond line 
\nthird line'
echo $AA
output:
first line
second line
third line
```

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` and `dash` (the ones I tested, should work for yours), you can use some Python-style triple-quote strings:

```bash
echo """Hello
World!"""
```

This outputs:

```
Hello
World!
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The triple quotes does nothing for multi-line text that single quotes doesn't already do. The first two and last two quotes will just evaluate to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. For me, piping the indented string into **sed** works nicely.

```sh
printf_strip_indent() {
   printf "%s" "$1" | sed "s/^\s*//g" 
}

printf_strip_indent "this is line one
this is line two
this is line three" > "file.txt"
```

This answer was based on *Mateusz Piotrowski*'s answer but refined a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention a simple one-line concatenation as it can be useful sometimes.

```
# for bash

v=" guga "$'\n'"   puga "

# Just for an example.
v2="bar "$'\n'"   foo "$'\n'"$v"

# Let's simplify the previous version of $v2.
n=$'\n'
v3="bar ${n}   foo ${n}$v"

echo "$v3"
```

You'll get something like this

```
bar 
   foo 
 guga 
   puga
```

All leading and ending white spaces will be preserved right for

```
echo "$v3" > filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Or keeping text indented with whitespaces:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' >filename <<EOF
    this is line one
    this is line two
    this is line three
EOF
```

Same but using a varible:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

text="$(sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' << whatever
    this is line one
    this is line two
    this is line three
)"

echo "$text" > filename
```

;-)