# How to execute multiline python code from a bash script?

Tags: python, bash, multiline

I need to extend a shell script (bash). As I am much more familiar with python I want to do this by writing some lines of python code which depends on variables from the shell script. Adding an extra python file is not an option.

```
result=`python -c "import stuff; print('all $code in one very long line')"`
```

is not very readable.

I would prefer to specify my python code as a multiline string and then execute it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a here-doc:

```
result=$(python <<EOF
import stuff
print('all $code in one very long line')
EOF
)
```

Comment: If one does not need the return value, is it then possible to ommit the "$("?

Comment: Yes. That's just the normal use of a here-document.

Answer (score 7):

Tanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222377/333403) I found the answer myself:

```
#!/bin/bash

# some bash code
END_VALUE=10

PYTHON_CODE=$(cat <<END
# python code starts here
import math

for i in range($END_VALUE):
    print(i, math.sqrt(i))

# python code ends here
END
)

# use the 
res="$(python3 -c "$PYTHON_CODE")"

# continue with bash code
echo "$res"
```

Comment: How to return two variables to "res"? Thanks.

Comment: res contains a string with the output. So you have to parse the string. Constructs like `a, b = "foo", "bar"` are imho not possible in bash.

Comment: This is great because it doesn't tie up `stdin`