# Why bash stops with parameter -e (set -e) when it meets read command?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is a simple script with parameter (set -e):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "begin"
read -r -d '' var <<- EOF
    echo "hello"
EOF
echo "${var}"
```

I expected no errors here, but the output is just:

> begin

And "echo $?" returns 1. Why is this happening? What is wrong with read command here. If I comment out "set -e", everything works fine.

Comment: As @Grisha suggested to add '|| :', I am going to add '|| true' to make it more readable. It works perfectly with 'set -e' command. Thanks everyone.

Comment: or put it before set -e

Answer (score 3):

Since you've specified `-d ''` (no delimiter), there is no complete input line so read is always hitting EOF and returning non-zero.

Comment: `-d ''` means NUL delimiter, isn't it?

Comment: I got this example of heredoc from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1655389/7561303. It works fine without (set -e), but I want to stop execution in case of error too. How do I do that?

Comment: Using `set -e` to trap errors is not very reliable.  See [BashFAQ105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `read` at all here.  If you want to use read with no delimiter, then you can just as easily make the assignment without it.  Just do `var='some multi-line string'`

Comment: Just change your command like `read -r -d '' FOO <<EOF || :`.  The `|| :` will make the exit code always true for the read command.

Comment: @Grisha That is a great idea! Note that, because of the way `-e` works, you can do any of `read ... && false`, or `read... || false`, or `read ... && true`.  Any use of a conditional will prevent the option from causing the script to exit.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, guys. I am going to use '|| true' at the end of the read command.