# Remove starting space tabs output echo multi-lined string

Tags: bash, shell

I am unable to figure out how to indent parts of bash script, preserving  indentation in the code. I want the output to be formatted with correctly without any tabs/spaces prefix to the output lines.

ex: script

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO1="something
output1"
INFO2="output2"
MY_INFO=INFO1

if [ True ]; then
    INFO="
    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    ${!MY_INFO}
    " 
fi
echo "${INFO}"
```

output returned:

```
    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    something
output1
```

expected output:

```
Here are the test results
bbb
ccc
aaa
something
output1
```

Comment: are you missing an `echo $INFO`?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: if you echo that double-quoted variable, it will print `$INFO` with the newlines and indent. if you echo it without the quotes you'll get it all on one line. If you want to `echo` something and have the output differ from that something, you'll have to strip the leading spaces with something like `sed`.

Comment: This question has [already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23929367/7541976) before.

Comment: @Varun, The Q concerns indentation in the source code, and is therefore unlike *Multi-line string with extra space (preserved indentation)*, which has no indention in the source.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes preserving spaces isn't a bug, it's a feature.  It's what double quotes are for.

The other problem is that `bash`, (unlike `python`), doesn't know a thing about indenting for readability -- to `bash` one unquoted space is the same as a thousand.

Various remedies:

1. Surrender indentation when multi-line strings are quoted, i.e.:

   ```
   if [ True ]; then
   INFO="
   Here are the test results
   bbb
   ccc
   aaa
   ${!MY_INFO}
   " 
   fi
   ```
2. Use `bash`, (or some other tool), to make the indents go away.  So first define an indented multi-line string:

   ```
    foo="
         bar
         baz"
   ```

   Then tweak *$foo* to remove spaces:

   ```
    foo="${foo// }"
   ```

   Now, *$foo* is no longer indented, but that would go too far if there are spaces that should have been kept.
3. Same as before, but at display time, (this is more wasteful), i.e.:

   ```
   echo  "${foo// }"
   ```