# What does OMG in a command line terminal mean?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, heredoc

I am starting with Linux bash scripting and I have found a bash script which uses:

```
my_command << OMG
..rest_of_commands
OMG
```

What does this `OMG` means? I have been searching about it but I did not found any information about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Its a [multiline heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930212/5625547) format.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's known as a here-doc (so now you can investigate further), it basically takes everything up to (but excluding) the `OMG` line and provides it as standard input to the `my_command` executable.

The `OMG` is any string that must match between the two areas and there are ways to allow for tabs and spaces to be ignored at the start of each line, but the basic concept is as I've described.

The following transcript shows it in action, where `cat` is used to copy standard input to standard output:

```
pax:~$ cat <<XYZZY
> hello
> there
> XYZZY
hello
there
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was searching incorrect thing, I was searching for "OMG" instead "<<"