# How to insert a variable in a SPARQL query with triple-quotation (""") in SPARQLWrapper (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sparql, double-quotes, sparqlwrapper

Very simple question about inserting a varaible in a SPARQL query in the Wrapper library. Example below in a Jupyter notebook, I defined a variable `'q'` outside SPARQL query, and would like to use it within a SPARQL query. I could not find out how to escape triple-quotation (`"""`). Quick help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

```
!pip install SPARQLWrapper
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, XML

q = '<http://data.europeana.eu/item/08517/3395FCFC5812F76279634269BE601072BF09183B>'
query_content = """
select *
where {
?providerProxy ore:proxyFor 'q' ; ?p ?o 
}
"""

query = prefix + query_content
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results)
print('------')
for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
  p = result["p"]["value"]
  o = result["o"]["value"]
  print(p + " : " + o)
```

Somehow the following method (.format) does not work.

```
query_content = """
select ?providerProxy
where {
?providerProxy ore:proxyFor {var}
}
LIMIT 100
""".format(var = '<http://data.europeana.eu/item/08517/3395FCFC5812F76279634269BE601072BF09183B>')

query = prefix + query_content
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
```

Error looks like:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in _query(self)
    925             else:
--> 926                 response = urlopener(request)
    927             return response, self.returnFormat

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

QueryBadFormed                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in _query(self)
    928         except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    929             if e.code == 400:
--> 930                 raise QueryBadFormed(e.read())
    931             elif e.code == 404:
    932                 raise EndPointNotFound(e.read())

QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: A bad request has been sent to the endpoint: probably the SPARQL query is badly formed. 
    results = sparql.query().convert()
    print(results)
    print('------')
```

Similarly, f""" {} """ method does not work:

```
var = '<http://data.europeana.eu/item/08517/3395FCFC5812F76279634269BE601072BF09183B>'
query_content = f"""
select ?providerProxy
where {
?providerProxy ore:proxyFor {var}
LIMIT 100
"""
```

returns error:

```
  File "<fstring>", line 2
    ?providerProxy ore)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: that is an quite often asked Python specific question, answers have been provided already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112614/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-python-string-with-inline-variables - like using `.format` is one option

Comment: Thank you for @UninformedUser for the reference. I tried out ```.format``` and ```f"{var}"```, but it does not work well. See the main question text for error messages. Cheers!

Comment: you have to escape curly braces of the query of course, otherwise it would be treated as format variable

Comment: Thank you. I made it like this:

```query_content = f"""
  select ?providerProxy
  where {{
  ?providerProxy ore:proxyFor {var} 
  }}
  """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query_content = f"""   select ?providerProxy   where {{   ?providerProxy ore:proxyFor {var}    }}   """`