# How to add variable bucket name in query InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

In Line 6  query = 'from(bucket: "my-bucket")\  how do we pass bucket as variable instead of hard-coding it ?

Code Source -> https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-python-and-influxdb-v2-0/
Script for writing and querying points to InfluxDB with the Python Client

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient

org = "my-org"
bucket = "my-bucket"
token = $my-token
query = 'from(bucket: "my-bucket")\
|> range(start: -10m)\
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "h2o_level")\
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "water_level")\
|> filter(fn: (r) => r.location == "coyote_creek")'
```

Note - the syntax style for query can be in these 2 ways as mentioned here - https://community.influxdata.com/t/query-throws-rparen-got-eof-error/18940

I tried multiple ways as mentioned here [How do I create a multiline Python string with inline variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112614/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-python-string-with-inline-variables) , but getting error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using concatenating strings and var.

```
org = "my-org"
bucket = "my-bucket"
token = $my-token
query = 'from(bucket: "' + my-bucket + '")\
|> range(start: -10m)\
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "h2o_level")\
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "water_level")\
|> filter(fn: (r) => r.location == "coyote_creek")'
```