# Doctor program - python

Tags: python

Below is a short doctor program that I am making and this is the start, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Here is the error I receive -
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

```
least = 0
most = 100

while True:
    try:
        levelofpain = int(input("How much is it hurting on a scale of", (least), "to", (most)))
        while llevelofpain < least or levelofpain > most:
            print ("Please enter a number from", (least), "to", (most))
            levelofpain = int(input("How much is it hurting on a scale of", (least), "to", (most)))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter a number from", (least), "to", (most))
```

Thanks in advance!

p.s. using python 3.3

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self-explanatory -- you are passing four arguments to `input(...)` where it is only accepting one.

The fix is to turn the argument into a single string.

```
levelofpain = int(input(
    "How much is it hurting on a scale of {} to {}? ".format(least, most)))
```

Comment: You could catenate `"string " + str(least) + " more string"` etc but that's hardly an improvement. Why would you want to avoid using a function? Functions are your friends.

Comment: `print (str("Please enter a number from", (least), "to", (most)))`

Answer (score 0):

For formatting strings, you probably want to use Python's `.format()` function.  Take a look at this question: [String Formatting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3)

There are two main methods for formatting strings in Python, the new way using the `.format` method of the `str` class, and the old C style method of using the `%` symbol:

**str.format():**

```
"This is a string with the numbers {} and {} and {0}".format(1, 2)
```

**C Style Format (%):**

```
"This is another string with %d %f %d" % (1, 1.5, 2)
```

I strongly recommend not using the C Style Format, instead use the modern function version.  Another way I don't recommend is replacing the input function with your own definition:

```
old_input = input
def input(*args):
    s = ''.join([str(a) for a in args])
    return old_input(s)

input("This", "is", 1, 2, 3, "a test: ")
```

Comment: @user3584575 The typical method is just to use the `.format()` member of string, but see my edit for two other alternatives.  You can also use the method triplee mentioned in his comment.