# What is the purpose of dollar sign in this Python3 string formatting expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

`"(%d goals, $%d)" % (self.goals, self.penalties)`

Original question: [String Formatting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3)

Python3 Format String Syntax Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: Did you consider just trying the expression? `"(%d goals, $%d)" % (42, 42)` immediately shows me that the `$` sign goes straight to the output string.

Comment: Upvoted. This is a perfectly legitimate question, and if I was a new user, I'd suspect that `$%` was some operator. We must try to be helpful and respectful to new users. (I remember when I used to do PERL and dabbled in PHP, it was like getting slowly beaten to death by the ASCII character set)

Comment: While the string formatting of python 3 does not use `$` anymore, it can have meaning if passing a string argument to `matplotlib` or other functions. So make sure and check the context of the string as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has no special meaning. It just inserts a `$` character:

```
>>> "(%d goals, $%d)" % (10, 42)
'(10 goals, $42)'
```

Sometimes a dollar is *just* a dollar.

You also linked to the wrong documentation; the formatting syntax documented there only applies to the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) and the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). You want to look at the [*`printf`-style String Formatting* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) instead.