# Create several csv files inside "for" loop - python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I hope you can help me with a very specific thing that I want to do in my python code.
So, I want to create a concrete number of csv files, I mean, I want to create a csv file for each material in a storage. 
At this moment I have:

```
nMat = 2 
for i in range(nMat):
      with open(infoVar[i].csv,'w') as f:
              writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n---------------\n')
              writer.writerow(['Id' + '  ' + 'Date & Time'])
```

This code obviously only creates a csv file named `infoVar[i]` but I wanted to create 2 csv files named `infoVar0` and `infoVar1` for example or something that creates several csv files.

Comment: `'infoVar{}.csv'.format(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do such a thing with plain string.

You need to format it with `'infoVar{}.csv'.format(i)`

Or using Python3.6 f-string `f'infoVar{i}.csv'`

Answer (score 0):

```
nMat = 2 
for i in range(nMat):

      filename = 'infoVar{i}.csv'.format(i)

      with open(filename,'w') as f:
              writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n---------------\n')
              writer.writerow(['Id' + '  ' + 'Date & Time'])
```

Here's a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3) to read up on about string formatting in Python - please take a look!