# How do parentheses work when printing a variable?

Tags: python

New to python (and coding in general) and was hoping for some help understanding this.

Here's some sample code from Ipify:

```
from requests import get

ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print('My public IP address is: {}'.format(ip))
```

I don't really understand how the braces are working in second line, but I've tried writing it a few other ways that I understand instead:

```
ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print(f"my public IP is {ip}")
```

and

```
ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print("my public IP is", ip)
```

My question is how is the code they provided in the first example better and what are the braces doing in their code?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you read the `str.format` docs? What do you mean *"better"*?

Comment: [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) can be found here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe By "better" I think OP just means its more widespread, most common use. I recall seeing somewhere it was preferred for python 3 rather than the old % method in python 2.

Comment: A reason for doing the first way is being written before Python 3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Formatting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3)

Comment: @Joel completely disagree, OP is asking why the first example is preferred to his other two. OP seems to be aware of the concept of string formatting...

Comment: @CapnJack I see now how the braces are working after reviewing str.format, but my question is indeed what the advantages to doing this vs the 2 other ways I added (which are shorter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Formatters work by putting in one or more replacement fields and
>   placeholders defined by a pair of curly braces `{}`

Example:

```
str = "This code is written in {}"
print(str.format("Python"))
```

Output:

```
This code is written in Python
```

**Why is `.format{}` better than old Python 2 `%`?**

`.format{}` accepts tuple while `%` throws a `TypeError`