# Python - MySQL queries with parametres and comas

Tags: python, mysql

I'm learning programming with python and trying to implement the safest possible MySQL queries starting with the simple SELECT ones. The problem is whenever I use coma in a query I got the following error:

```
cursor.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 536, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I am aware of the fact that coma itself isn't a source of a problem but I tried many different MySQL syntax and everytime I use a come I got this "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'" error.

I also tried to change MySQL database encoding - nothing changes. The code is below.

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    charset='utf8',
    # init_command='SET NAMES UTF8',
    host="10.0.0.234",
    user="x",
    passwd="x>",
    database="x",
)

print(conn.is_connected())

param = "test"

cursor = conn.cursor()

# =========== query below does work ========

# query = ("SELECT * from list WHERE username LIKE '%test%'")



# ============ query below does work =======

# query = ("SELECT * from list HAVING username = '%s'" % param)



# ============ query below doesn't work =====

# query = ("SELECT * from list HAVING username = %s", (param,))



# ============= query below doesn't work =====

query = "SELECT * from list WHERE username = :name", {'name': param}





cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for x in result:
    print(x)

conn.close()
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little bit tricky, but it is in essence because of what the actual value of the 'query' variable is...

For example:

```
# 1.
query = ("SELECT * from list WHERE username LIKE '%test%'")
# when you do this, query is a string variable,
# NB: the parentheses are not necessary here

# so when you call
cursor.execute(query)
# the value passed into the execute call is the string "SELECT * from list WHERE username LIKE '%test%'"

# 2.
query = ("SELECT * from list HAVING username = '%s'" % param)
# when you do this, query is the result of a string formatting operation
# This is a Python 2 form of string formatting
# The discussion here probably makes it more clear: 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3

# it is almost the same as doing this:
query = "SELECT * from list HAVING username = 'test'"

# so when you call
cursor.execute(query)
# the value passed into the execute call is the string "SELECT * from list HAVING username = 'test'"

# 3. 
query = ("SELECT * from list HAVING username = %s", (param,))
# This operation is assigning a 2-value tuple into the query variable
# The first value in the tuple is the string "SELECT * from list HAVING username = %s"
# The second value in the tuple is a 1-value, with 'test' as its first value

# 4.
query = "SELECT * from list WHERE username = :name", {'name': param}
# This is similar to #3, but the values in the tuple are instead
# query[0] == "SELECT * from list WHERE username = :name"
# query[1] is a dictionary: {'name': param}
```

Both 3 and 4 above are not calling the MySQL `execute` with the parameters you are expecting ([see API here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)). You probably need to do one of:

1. unpack the query tuple into separate variables, and call the function with them

   ```
   operation, params = query # unpack the first elem into operation, and second into params
   cursor.execute(operation, params)
   ```
2. just index into the query tuple

   ```
   cursor.execute(query[0], query[1])
   # NB: you could also use the 'named parameters' feature in Python
   cursor.execute(query[0], params=query[1])
   ```
3. Use the 'unpacking arguments list' ([SPLAT operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator))

   ```
   cursor.execute(*query)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much Doodie! Of course it worked as you wrote it will. But the most important thing is that now I know what was the real reason of my problem. You provided very detailed and understandable explanation, thanks! Gonna try doing more complex MySQL operations now with more parametres. Cheers!