# How to stop repetition in python format()

Tags: python, format

I have a string as follows:

”This 1 is just a 1 and 1 is just a number. And 1 + 1 is equal to 2”

When I want to use python format it would be something like:

```
var = 1
test = "This {} is just a {} and {} is just a number. And {} + {} is equal to 2".format(var,var,var,var,var)
```

But I would like to know if there is any quick replacement for str.format() in python for avoid repetition. Something like:

```
test = "This {} is just a {} and {} is just a number. And {} + {} is equal to 2".format(var*)
```

Comment: Does your format string "know" that all its placeholders are supposed to refer to the same value? Or do you just incidentally want to fill all placeholders with the same value?

Comment: The answers to this question, ['String formatting in Python 3'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13945749/8944057), have some example string formatting usage that might be helpful.

Comment: You can do `print("This {v} is just a {v} and {v} is just a number. And {v} + {v} is equal to 2".format(v=var))`. Or with a f-string: `print(f"This {var} is just a {var} and {var} is just a number. And {var} + {var} is equal to 2")`

Comment: @deceze I think placeholders are supposed to refer to the same value, and probably a simple indexing should solve my problem. Thanks