# Python error: "TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3" (betting simulator)

Tags: python

I decided that I would write a code to simulate a betting game, where you guess the number the dice will land on. Eventually, the code became a full-blown simulator, with credit-card withdrawals and different dice types and stakes (don't ask me why there's a 4-sided dice, I doubt it's possible).

Anyway, I kept getting the same error. This is my code:

```
import random
from random import randint
diea = randint(1,4)
dieb = randint(1,5)
diec = randint(1,6)
jackpot = randint(1,30)
chance = randint (1,30)
cquit = "a"
bal = 10
credcard = 100
withdrawal = 0
deposit = 0
if jackpot == chance:
    print("You won the jackpot of 10k!")
    bal = bal + 10000
while cquit.lower() == "a":
    print ("Your balance is $", bal)
    print ("Your credit card balance is $", credcard)
    choicea = input("Would you like to deposit / withdraw money - a for deposit, b for withdrawal, anything else to skip:    ")
    if choicea.lower() == "a":
            deposit = int(input("How much would you like to deposit - you have $", bal," on you right now:    "))
            if deposit > bal:
                    print ("You do not have enough money - cancelling process")
            else:
                    credcard = deposit + credcard
                    bal = bal - deposit
                    print ("Your balance is $", bal)
                    print ("Your credit card balance is", credcard)
    if choicea.lower() == "b":
        withdrawal = int(input("How much money would you like to withdraw - you have $", credcard," on your card"))
        if withdrawal > credcard:
                    print ("Your card does not allow overdrafts - cancelling process")
        else:
                    bal = withdrawal + bal
                    credcard = credcard - withdrawal
                    print ("Your balance is $", bal)
    bet = int(input("How much would you like to bet?:    "))
    if bet > bal:
        print ("You do not have enough money")
    else:
        diechoice = input("Choose die - A (1-4, x2), B (1-5, x3), C(1-6, x4):    ")
        if diechoice.lower() == "a":
                guess = int(input("What will the die land on?:  "))
                if guess == diea:
                    print ("Correct guess - balance doubled")
                    bal = bal + bet
                if guess > 4:
                  print ("That is above the die's capacity - bet cancelled")
                if guess != diea:
                  print ("Incorrect guess - bet removed from balance")
                bal = bal - bet
        if diechoice.lower() == "b":
                guess = int(input("What will the die land on?:  "))
                if guess == diea:
                    print ("Correct guess - tripling balance")
                    bet = bet*2
                    bal = bal + bet
                if guess > 5:
                    print ("That is above the die's capacity - bet cancelled")
                if guess != dieb:
                    print ("Incorrect guess - bet removed from balance")
                    bal = bal - bet
        if diechoice.lower() == "c":
                guess = int(input("What will the die land on?:  "))
                if guess == diea:
                    print ("Correct guess - quadrupling balance")
                    bet = bet*3
                    bal = bal + bet
                if guess > 6:
                    print ("That is above the die's capacity - cancelling bet")
                if guess != diec:
                    print ("Incorrect guess - bet removed from balance")
                    bal = bal - bet
        elif diechoice.lower() != "a" and diechoice.lower() != "b" and diechoice.lower() != "c":
            print ("Incorrect input - skipping bet")
        cquit = input("a to continue, anything else to end:    ")
        if cquit.lower() == "a":
            if bal == 0 and credcard == 0:
                print ("ending program - you are bankrupt")
                cquit = "b"
            if bal > 0:
                print ("continuing program")
                print ("...")
                print ("...")
                print ("...")
        else:
            print ("ending program")
```

This is the error I get in the code when testing it. It happens when I enter a or b on the first input statement whenever it loops:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FAKE NEWS\du.py", line 30, in <module>
    withdrawal = int(input("How much money would you like to withdraw - you have $", credcard," on your card"))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

I've been reading other reports on the same errors but I'm too bad at Python to understand any of it.

Comment: As an aside, [a four-sided die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sided_die) is definitely a thing that exists

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is not like `print()`, you can't give it multiple arguments and expect it to concatenate them automatically in the prompt.

You have to do the string formatting yourself.

```
withdrawal = int(input("How much money would you like to withdraw - you have $%.2f on your card" % (credcard)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing three arguments to `input`, but it only takes one.

To put a number into a string, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
prompt = "You have ${} on your card.".format(dollars)
input(prompt)
```

This inserts the value of `dollars` as the first "replacement field" (`{}`), formatting it by calling `str`. You can add multiple replacement fields, and you can name them like so:

```
"x is {}, y is {}".format(x, y)
"x is {1}, y is {0}".format(y, x) # note switched arguments
"x is {x} y is {y}".format(x=x, y=y)
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or later, you can use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) instead:

```
current_balance = 100;

f"You have ${current_balance} on your card."
```

There are many other things you can do with the [string-formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13945777/7389264) provides a quick look at a few of them, if you don't want to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
deposit = int(input("How much would you like to deposit - you have $" + str(bal) + " on you right now:    "))
```

and

```
withdrawal = int(input("How much money would you like to withdraw - you have $"+ str(credcard) + " on your card"))
```

Answer (score 0):

change input line from

deposit = int(input("How much would you like to deposit - you have $", bal," on you right now:    "))

to

deposit = int(input("How much would you like to deposit - you have $"+str(bal)+" on you right now:    "))