# How to print a date with dashes?

Tags: python

I'm quite lost and I'm in need of trying to format some code so it ends up having dashes in the date. I can get 3, 12, 28 but I can't get 3-12-28. I am a super new beginner so I'm quite lost at the moment.

```
    year = 3
    month = 12
    day = 28
    print(date)
```

Comment: Are you using something like `datetime` module or just pure strings?

Comment: `print(f'{year}-{month}-{day}')` to begin with, but this will become problematic for a day or month `< 10`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
print("{0}-{1}-{2}".format(year,month,day))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use datetime to format the result

```
import datetime

year = 3
month = 12
day = 28

dt = (datetime.date(year, month, day))
print(dt)
```

the result will be 0003-12-28

if you want more examples of datetime you could take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are new to python you can concatenate the strings together.

```
year = 3
month = 12
day = 28
date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
print(date)
```

Alternatively you can use format to set the variables in your required format.

```
print(f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
```

Another method is to use datetime if you are using todays date

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)
```