# Why should I use str.format?

Tags: python-3.x

What does str.format do? Why should I use it? What's the difference between using

```
print(a, b)
```

and

```
print("{} {}".format(a, b))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please  read this https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: In your above example there is really no use for it. But you can do with it alot of special things, like align strings and save yourself the `str()` conversion for numbers just to name a few benefits. Read https://pyformat.info/ to see more benefits

Comment: Some more examples from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3 ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: You should use [f-strings: PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) because they're easier to read. `print(f'{a} {b}')`

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theformat()method takes the arguments or variables which are passed, formats them, and places them in the string wherever the placeholders{}symbol is used.

```
a = 5

#single formatting
b = "My name is XYZ & my age is just {}"
print (b.format(a))

#multiple formatting
c = "My name is XYZ & my age is just {}. Also I have a sibling who's age is also {}"
print(c.format(a, a))
```

﻿

```
Output:
```

﻿     My name is XYZ & my age is just 5
﻿     My name is XYZ & my age is just {}. Also I have a sibling who's age is also 5

Comment: one more use                                                                                                       
#multiple formatting with indexing
c = "My name is {2} & my age is just {0}. Also I have a sibling who's age is {1}"
print(c.format(5, 8, "XYZ"))


Output:
My name is XYZ & my age is just 5. Also I have a sibling who's age is 8