# python----The name of the error is'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'(っ °Д °;)っ

Tags: python

I was making a program that inputs a number, distinguishes whether the number is prime, and prints it.

And when I type'o', I put the function to run the program once more.

Below is the program

```py
print('Prime number distinction')
print('=' * 50)
again = 'o'
while again == 'o':
    s = 0
    a = 0
    i = 0
    pn = input('Please enter a number')
    pn = int(pn)
    if pn == 2 or pn == 3:
        print('%dis a prime number' %pn)
    else:
        for i in range(2, pn):
                if pn % i == 0:
                    print('%dis not a prime number.' %pn)
                    a = pn/i
                    i = str(i)
                    pn = str(pn)
                    a = int(a)
                    print(pn+'='+i+'x'+'%d' %a)
                    
                else:
                    s = s + 1
        if s == pn - 2:
            print('%dis a prime number.' %pn)
    
    again = input('Enter o to do it one more time.')
```

But 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'
An error occurred.
Strangely, after the program worked as intended, an error occurred.

```py
line 13, in <module>
    if pn % i == 0:
```

There was an error in the part called,
However, it is an essential part of the program operation,
If an error occurs here, the whole program will have to break.
I wonder why.

I will modify the program.
Many people have told me to add a 'break'statement

```py
print('Prime number distinction')
print('=' * 50)
again = 'o'
while again == 'o':
    s = 0
    a = 0
    i = 0
    pn = input('Please enter a number')
    pn = int(pn)
    if pn == 2 or pn == 3:
        print('%dis a prime number' %pn)
    else:
        for i in range(2, pn):
                if pn % i == 0:
                    print('%dis not a prime number.' %pn)
                    a = pn/i
                    i = str(i)
                    str_pn = str(pn)  # use a new variable str_pn
                    a = int(a)
                    print(str_pn+'='+i+'x'+'%d' %a) # use str_pn here
                    break
                else:
                    s = s + 1
        if s == pn - 2:
            print('%dis a prime number.' %pn)
    
    again = input('Enter o to do it one more time.')
```

Now the result is printed only once.
Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: 1. What input value gives you that error? 2. Please paste the full error message, not just the beginning.

Comment: You need to provide the error/traceback for your problem.  Also, I would recommend using f-strings in place of interpolation.  `f"{pn} is a prime number"` in place of `"%d is a prime number" % pn`, `f"{pn}={i}x{a}" ` in place of `str(pn)+'='+i+'x'+'%d' %a)`, etc.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Yo should get to know its debugging features. If not The [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) module is worth learning.

Comment: If you use string formatting you won't need to *make* `pn` a str - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13945777/2823755, https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is trying to compute `pn % 2` when you have already converted `pn` to a `string`

**Solution** (check out the commented lines)

```
print('Prime number distinction')
print('=' * 50)
again = 'o'
while again == 'o':
    s = 0
    a = 0
    i = 0
    pn = input('Please enter a number')
    pn = int(pn)
    if pn == 2 or pn == 3:
        print('%dis a prime number' %pn)
    else:
        for i in range(2, pn):
                if pn % i == 0:
                    print('%dis not a prime number.' %pn)
                    a = pn/i
                    i = str(i)
                    # pn = str(pn)  # remove this line
                    a = int(a)
                    print(str(pn)+'='+i+'x'+'%d' %a) # add str(pn) around pn
                    
                else:
                    s = s + 1
        if s == pn - 2:
            print('%dis a prime number.' %pn)
    
    again = input('Enter o to do it one more time.')
```

Comment: I'd like to add one more thing. In the if pn % i == o: statement, include a break statement at the end or it's going to print the answer twice

Comment: i don't see what you mean. when i execute it only prints once.

Comment: try inputing 10. it printed twice when i did that