# how can i add an integer value in the middle of a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am variable which is a file path ie C:\temp
Inside temp i have csv files all with the format `number01.csv   number02.csv` and so on x amount of times

what my script does is read the original csv file from temp do some modifications and then creates an updated csv file.

right now each time i have to change the file path indivdually but i am looking for a way to automate it

this is what I am trying to do

```
numbers= [5,6,7,8]
for x in number:
    file_name =  'C:\\temp\number{x}.csv'
    output_file = 'C:\\temp\number{x}_rev.csv'
```

how can i add an integer value in the middle of a string in python3?

Comment: You need to use an f-string `f'...'`. Try `f'C:\\temp\number{x}.csv'`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3

Comment: You need to double up the backslashes everywhere, not just the first time.

Comment: @DYZ that link does not answer the question. They want string interpolation https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: @flakes Which is one of the answers.

Comment: @DYZ how about this question instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation