# python2.7 - selenium using for loop to find element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a script to automatically fill in timecard for my work. I'm having trouble implementing for loop with selenium though.

For example, i have these many lines:

```
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_1_r1").send_keys(8)
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_2_r1").send_keys(8)
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_3_r1").send_keys(8)
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_4_r1").send_keys(8)
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_5_r1").send_keys(8)
```

and I would like to shorten them:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_[i]_r1").send_keys(8)
```

However, I get this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Could someone please help? I have python 2.7 and use chrome as my browser.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string, but I don't have a dupe hammer since the question was originally tagged differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[i]` would not auto-magically be replaced by the value of the `i` variable, you should "format" it into the string instead:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    browser.find_element_by_id("t_z12022421023027015111a68_b_{i}_r1".format(i=i)).send_keys(8)
```