# What is the correct syntax for using a variable and following-sibling in Python Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python and Selenium Webdriver.

I have the following code which works as expected:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[text()="text"]/../following-sibling::td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class ="class_name"]')
```

I would like to change the above "text" to a variable, similar to the below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[text()="%s"] % variable_name/../following-sibling::td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class ="class_name"]')
```

This doesn't work as it isn't a valid XPath express. Can anyone help with the correct coding please?

Edit:
Also, if there is a way to search for text in the follow-sibling that would also be useful. Something similar to:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[text()="%s"] % variable_name/../following-sibling:[div@text()= "text"]')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting a variable inside a string (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/putting-a-variable-inside-a-string-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote `'//p[text()="%s"] % variable_name/../following-sibling::td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class ="class_name"]'`, you created a string that *literally contains* `%s` and `% variable_name`.  The `%` operator and the variable(s) to be substituted go outside of the string literal:

```
'//p[text()="%s"]/../following-sibling::td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class ="class_name"]' % variable_name
```