# How to insert variable string into multiline comment in Python?

Tags: python, comments

I want do define a Python function with `exec` like this:

```
exec """def my_func(alpha = 'a'):
  return alpha"""
```

It works. However, for a specific reason I want to to define the `alpha = 'a'` in a separate string:

```
s = "alpha = 'a'"
exec """def my_func(s):
  return alpha"""
```

but this one doesn't work. Is there a way to insert a string variable content into multiline comment string this way?

Comment: Why are you doing this with `exec`? What is your actual use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)

Comment: This is not a "multiline comment", it's a triple quoted (multiline) string literal. The fact that triple quoted strings are often used as docstrings does not make them comments. And since it's a string literal, all the usual string formatting operations (which are extensively documented) are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [format](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function:

```
s = "alpha = 'a'"
exec """def my_func({}):
  return alpha""".format(s)
```