# for loop and file saving

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Jupyter and which is working on pyspark(python).

I have used "for" loop to iterate the process and trying to save the file after each iteration.

for example:

```
name = "mea"
for i in range(2):
    print "name[i]"
    i +=1
```

and output is:

```
name[i]
name[i]
```

this above algorithm is the short explaination related to the main algorithm that i am working on.

the problem is it is giving an output name[i] and I want it to give me name[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwsu.jpg) and for second iteration name[2].

I need to use " " because i wanted to save my file to specific folder and i need to speacify the path in " ". So after firsdt iteration it should save the file as name[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwsu.jpg) and after second iteration it should save the file as name[2].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwsu.jpg)

so from image in my actual algorithm, result is the output that i am getiing after each for loop iteration and for each output, i wanted to save it in new files like result[0],result[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwsu.jpg),result[2] instead of result[i],result[i],result[i]. because the latter one, it is **replacing** the file to the old one.

Comment: give name of file as name+"["+str(i)+"]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has nothing specific to pyspark that you are trying to achieve.  As per your example, what you need is  - use of variable in strings,
so this will suffice for your example:

```
name = "mea"
for i in range(2):
    print "name[%s]" % i  
    i +=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your print statement as follows

```
print "name[" + str(i) + "]"
```