# removing curly brackets from tkinter label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I try to make a label with text with a "x" variable inside the text. My problem is that the label has curly brackets. here is a sample of my code. how do I remove them?

```
victory_screen=Label(root,compound=CENTER, text=("PLAYER 1 WINS with 
",x,"points""\n""\n""\n""\n""\n""\n"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)

Comment: you have to create one string using concatenation. Or use [string formatting: PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `,`s with `+`s. As in:

```
victory_screen=Label(root,compound=CENTER, text=("PLAYER 1 WINS with " + x + " points""\n""\n""\n""\n""\n""\n"))
```

Comment: wont't work if he has set a StrVar() , needs to use str(StrVar()) to be able to use +