# How to name my file based on a randomly generated number?

Tags: python, string

I want to name my file as the student number comes up.

Here is the code:

```
import random
SNumber=random.randint(199999,999999)
print(SNumber)
writefile=open("studentNumberhere.txt","a")
writefile.write(SNumber)
writefile.close()
```

If the code runs and it generates the number: 123456

The filename would be 123456.txt

And if I generate another number, there will be another file appearing on my folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
SNumber=random.randint(199999,999999)
print(SNumber)
writefile = open(str(SNumber)+'.txt','a')
writefile.write(str(SNumber))
writefile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
writefile = open(str(SNumber)+'.txt','a')
```

If the file does not exists, `open(name,'r+')` will fail.

You can use `open(name, 'w')`, which creates the file if the file does not exist, but it will truncate the existing file.

Alternatively, you can use `open(name, 'a');` this will create the file if the file does not exist, but will not truncate the existing file.

```
import sys
import random
def create():
SNumber=random.randint(199999,999999)
try:
    writefile = open(str(SNumber)+'.txt','a')
    writefile.write(SNumber)
    writefile.close()
except:
    print("Error occurred.")
    sys.exit(0)

create()
```

Comment: Hi sir, what if i will open the said file for file checker. umm because if the data already exists in the file. it will be discarded.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with `Python`. And so, not understand your comment.

Comment: If you have used `open(name, 'a')` then it will not be discarded. `open(name, 'w')` will discard earlier data's in file

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: yes sir. it helped. just my 2nd code does not jam with your code. and it is my only problem sir. Thank You