# Output json txt name in Python

Tags: python, json

I need help changing the name of the .txt output file to the date inside the json file, is it possible?

Json:

```
"date": "2018-03-21",
```

python:

```
import urllib.request, json

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.fixer.io/latest?&base=EUR") as url:
    data=json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)

    with open('*changeNameHere*{}.txt'.format(*Example*), 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data["rates"], outfile)
```

Comment: ??? Replace `*Example*` with `data['date']`? That's your question?

Comment: yes, with the date inside the json file if its possible.

Comment: Of course it's possible and I just showed you how. What's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
import urllib.request, json

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.fixer.io/latest?&base=EUR") as url:
    data=json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)

    with open('{}.txt'.format(data['date']), 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data["rates"], outfile)
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider marking the answer as correct