# how to build create table script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an Oracle table using Python 3.5. I have the column names and data type stored in a dictionary, and I want to create an SQL statement (stored in `sql_stmt`) to execute it from Python. My dictionary looks like this:

```
adict1 = {'col1': 'Number', 'col2': 'Date', 'col3': 'Date'}
```

I am trying to create an SQL statement which looks like this:

```
create table dummy(col1 Number, col2 Date, col3 Date)
```

So, I was trying to create the SQL statement by looping through the dictionary keys:

```
sql_stmt = "create table"

for key in adict1 :
   sql_stmt = sql_stmt + ("dummy('%s' , '%s')" ,(key,adict1[key]))
```

But it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#413>", line 2, in <module>
sql_stmt = sql_stmt + ("dumm5('%s' , '%s')" ,(key,adict1[key]))
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the table name and opening bracket outside the loop, make sure the comma is in the right place, use `{}` and `.format` to format your string with the variables, remove the last comma, then add the closing bracket.

```
adict1 = {'col1': 'Number', 'col2': 'Date', 'col3': 'Date'}

sql_stmt = "create table dummy("

for key in adict1 :
   sql_stmt = sql_stmt + ("{} {}, ".format(key,adict1[key]))

sql_stmt = sql_stmt[:-2]
sql_stmt += ")"
```

Then `sql_stmt` is `"create table dummy(col2 Date, col3 Date, col1 Number)"`.

Answer (score 1):

there is a error when you plus the string:

```
sql_stmt = sql_stmt + ("dumm5('%s' , '%s')" ,(key,adict1[key]))
```

you can format it like this:

```
sql_stmt = sql_stmt + 'dumm5({0}, {1})'.format(key, adict1[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic solution:

```
adict1 = {'col1':'Number', 'col2':'Date', 'col3':'Date'}
sql_stmt = "create table dummy(%s)" % ', '.join(key+' '+val for key,val in adict1.items())
```

but it may appear somewhat "over-pythonic"...