# Place a string within a string

Tags: python, string

I want to do something along the lines of

```
print("hello, your name is [name]")
```

but I don't want to do it like

```
print("hello, your name is "+name)
```

because I want to be able to place `[name]` anywhere in the string.

Is there some way to do this in python?

Comment: What does _anywhere in the string_ mean?

Comment: You want to use string formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From python3.6 you can use f string:

```
print(f'your name is {name}')
```

Or you can use format:

```
print('your name is {}'.format(name))
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1, old style formatting.

```
>>> name = 'Jake'
>>> print('hello %s, have a great time!' % name)
hello Jake, have a great time!
```

Option 2, using `str.format`.

```
>>> print('hello {}, have a great time!'.format(name))
hello Jake, have a great time!
```

Option 3, string concatenation.

```
>>> print('hello ' + name + ', have a great time!')
hello Jake, have a great time!
```

Option 4, format strings (as of Python 3.6).

```
>>> print(f'hello {name}, have a great time!')
hello Jake, have a great time!
```

Option 2 and 4 are the [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) ones. For a good overview of Python string formatting, check out [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info).

Comment: It's just missing [template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings).

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f"hello, your name is {name}")
```

It is called an f-string: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

There are other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is called string formatting: `print('Hello, my name is {}'.format(name))`

You can do something more complex as well:

```
print('Hello, my name is {0}, and here is my name again {0}'.format(name)'
```

Answer (score 0):

`print("hello, your name is %s" % ('name'))` also works for you.

You can extend it to more variables like:

```
>>> print("%s, your name is %s" % ('hello', 'name'))
hello, your name is name
```