# cURL : change parse data with list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I have a problem to parse the "data" to data in curl command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"data":"traffic cun cun je"}' http://68.xxx.236.113/api/
```

Above is my curl command. And after I use, https://curl.trillworks.com/ to convert curl command to Python, I got this

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
data = '{"data":"traffic cun cun je"}'
response = requests.post('http://68.xxx.236.113/api/', headers=headers, data=data)
```

The problem is, how can I change the `"data":"CHANGE HERE"` with the data in a list ***(text)***

Below is my code for the list:

```
with open('hai.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for line in data:
        text=line['text']
        loc=line['location']
        i.append(text)
        u.append(loc)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python

Comment: @Heavy Octane thank you, already tried with `data = urllib.parse.quote('{"data":"%s"}'%text)` , but i need the quote like this `'{"data":"apa la"}'` instead of `{"data":"apa la"}`