# printing a string loop with range

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I am trying to make the following print , but cannot make this print goes from 1 to 100

```
 for name in range(1,100):

 print(/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[name]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a)
```

The idea is to print those all these string value 100 times which goes from 1 to 100 inside li

Comment: In the question, your indentation is not correct, and your string isn't surrounded by quotes. Are these correct in your code?

Comment: `range(a,b)` counts from `a` to `b-1`.  Use `range(1,101)` to count 1-100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar as below with f-string formatting

```
for name in range(1,101):
    print(f"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{name}]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a")
```

updated: 
1. correct the `range(1, 101)`
2. f-string was supported since Python 3.6+

Comment: 101 instead of 100 and this solution is only for Python 3.6+

Answer (score 3):

Your indent is not correct in the second line, and your string is not correct.

This is my solution

```
for name in range(1,100):
    print("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[" + str(name) + "]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a")
```

You can reference here for more ways how to add variable in a string [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python)