# what does this syntax error means. I wrote my code good. What is the problem?

Tags: python-3.x

why do I get this problem: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. Can someone please tell me where my fault is.

```
a = 2
b = 4
c = 8
print ("Forced Order:" 'a', '*' ('c' '+' 'b') '=’ a*(c+b))
```

Comment: As written, your quotation marks are not properly balanced. What you _actually_ wanted to do was to [insert variable values into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

The EOL error specifically appears because of `'*' ('c' '+' 'b')`. The computer believes that this code is trying to run a function, much like `print()`. The error pops up because a string cannot call a function like this.

What I imagine your trying to do is make the function output is `Forced Order: a*(c+b)=24`.That can be solved with two quick fixes:

First, there's a typo. `'=’` should use `'` not `’` on both sides.

Second, the parenthesis need to be parts of the string. The parenthesis in `('c' '+' 'b')` are not part of any strings. Either they can be individually turned into strings like the rest of the function or, just like with the string `"Forced Order:"`, the string `"a*(c+b)"` can be written out as one string instead of concatenating a series of single characters.