# how to wite a update query in psql. it shows column does not exist

Tags: python, web-scraping, psql

This is the query I tried, but it does not work, it gives me the error as if the column does not exist.

I have the table `Gzip_master`, it contains the `status` column but when i try to execute the update it gives me

> update_value column does not exist

Here's my code:

```
update_value = "Scraped"
query = 'UPDATE "Gzip_Master" SET "status"=update_value WHERE status IS null'
self.curs.execute(query)
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: column "update_value" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "Gzip_Master" SET status="update_value" WHERE status ...

Comment: above comment is my error, what to do ? i'm trying every thing

Comment: you are not saying what language you are using, but i think the problem is that you wanted to place the value of `update_value` inside your query, but instead you put the string there. depending on your language, it might be something like `query = 'UPDATE "Gzip_Master" SET "status"=' + update_value + ' WHERE status IS null'`

Comment: i'm using python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the text `update_value` inside the query-String is just text and does not get replace by the variable value you define above that. Also, the value `Scraped` you define is a string and not a column name, you need to also mark it in the query string (see the single quotes below; [you need escape them with a `\` as they appear inside a single-quoted string themselves)](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). Try like this:

```
update_value = "Scraped"
query = 'UPDATE "Gzip_Master" SET "status"=\'' + update_value + '\' WHERE status IS null'
self.curs.execute(query)
```

There are [many other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string-in-python) to put the value of `update_value` into the string.