# Is there a way to pass variable from loop to find_element_by_xpath regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I m trying to pass values of string to find_element_by_Xpath() to get the search and match for the part of value of attribute. How do I get this working?

I have tried it on Python3.7 and selenium library, Can't find a way to pass value from loop. I was trying with the following but doesn't work

```
datasets = [  'ds_pos_retail_outlet','ds_pos_retail_fullset', 'ds_pos_retail_ProfitCenter','ds_pos_retail_Section']

for x in datasets :

    refreshNow= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[starts-with(@aria-describedby, x) and @title="Refresh now"]')
    refreshNow.click()
    time.sleep(8)
```

I want to select and click a node with property value as passed with regex match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Comment: What regex are you referring to? You aren't using any regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `format()`:

```
xpath = '//button[starts-with(@aria-describedby, {}) and @title="Refresh now"]'.format(x)
refreshNow= driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Comment: I think there is some problem here. I can't suppose to make it work. It is clicking the button with aria-describedby = " ds_pos_retail_fullsetdatasetMenu4". I was hoping this would work but unfortunately not for my case I think. Even though the dataset[1] element is "ds_pos_retail_outlet"

Comment: @Tayyab List indexes start at 0, so I think you mean `dataset[0]`. From here, you will need to verify that your xpath is correct to select the element you want.

Comment: Okay, I get it working. Actually the issue is resolved by adding quotes  at this part of you code like this " { } "

Comment: @Tayyab That makes sense. So for example `ds_pos_retail_outlet` needs to have quotes around it. That is part of the xpath syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the format function, you can use simple string concatenation.

```
refreshNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[starts-with(@aria-describedby, ' + x + ') and @title="Refresh now"]')
```

Comment: Note that the string is surrounded by single quotes. So this won't quite work the way the OP wants.