# How to use a variable in a string in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I have a Python code in which I am using `useruser` as my username:

```
zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', 'C:\Users\useruser\company\folder-images')
```

How can I update this code to get the logged-in username?

For example this is what I tried:

```
myuser = os.popen("echo %username%").read().replace("\n","")
```

...and then when I print `myuser`, I get the right username:

```
print(myuser)
```

How can I use this variable in my code, instead of `useruser`?

Comment: `zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', 'C:\\Users\\{}\\company\\folder-images'.format(myuser))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**concatenate**](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) your `myuser` variable to your string like this:

```
zipfolder("tgs-stealed", "C:\Users\\" + myuser + "\company\folder-images")
```

Or use [**`str.format()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
zipfolder("tgs-stealed", "C:\Users\{}\company\folder-images".format(myuser))
```

Also, as mentioned by @AbdulNiyasPM in the comments, you can use an [**f-string**](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) with Python 3.6+:

```
zipfolder("tgs-stealed", f"C:\Users\{myuser}\company\folder-images")
```

Comment: From python 3.6 onwards there is one more option available. **f-strings**

Comment: thanks this code worked. but i have any more question. in my code the directory ziped and saved with name tgs-stealed.zip on my current directory. but i want save the zipped file on c:\shared-files folder. how can do this? please edit my code and show me.

Comment: @john This is a completely different issue, you should create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> In Python have many forms. But to this string, you need prefix the
>   string with r (to produce a raw string).

String concatenation:

```
zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', r'C:\Users\\' + str(myuser) + '\company\folder-images')
```

Conversion Specifier:

```
zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', r'C:\Users\\%s\company\folder-images' % myuser)
```

Using local variable names:

```
zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', r'C:\Users\\%(myuser)s\company\folder-images' % locals())
```

Using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', r'C:\Users\\{0}\company\folder-images'.format(myuser))
```

Using f-strings:

```
zipfolder('shared-photo.zip', r'C:\Users\\{myuser}\company\folder-images')) # added in Python 3.6
```

Adapted from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string/2962966#2962966).