# how to insert variable into a re.compile in python

Tags: python

Good morning I have the following problem, I want to build the following regular expression:
pattern = re.compile ('[/*AB] P79CAN01 [#] ?'), where the value of "P79COL01" comes from a variable, for example I have the variable:

equipo = 'P79CAN01', but I don't know how to enter it into re.compile

```
equipo='P79CAN01';

patron=re.compile('[/*AB]P79CAN01[#]?')
```

I saw that you already asked the question at [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string), but I did not understand much the answer, besides it is quite old

Comment: `'[/*AB]{}[#]?'.format(equipo)` or since 3.6 `f'[/*AB]{equipo}[#]?'`

Comment: This is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string