# How to get xpath of data in the columns in this dynamic webtable(python,selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have following dynamic webtable

```
(checkbox)   ID_No  country_code  Date          Time           UserName          FileName
            1       5           10/04/2019    12:05:45       xyz@gmail.com      filename1
            2       7           10/04/2019    13:05:45       pqr@gmail.com      filename2
            3       8           10/03/2019    14:05:45       pqr@gmail.com      filename2
            4       9           10/04/2019    14:08:45       pqr@gmail.com      filename1
```

On the left hand side of the id_no there is a checkbox.I only want to check the rows where FileName='filename1'
and Date='10/04/2019'

when I use this xpath in the chrome console: `$x("//tr[td[contains(text(),'filename1')]]")[0]'`

This contains 1st row that contains "filename1" value.I get following HTML for the rows of this webtable

```
<tr class="class1">
  <td width="2%"> </td>   <!–– checkbox ––>
  <td width="2%"> 1 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 5 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 10/04/2019 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 12:05:45 </td>
  <td width="2%" style=word-wrap:break-word> xyz@gmail.com </td>
  <td width="2%"> filename1 </td>
</tr>
```

To check the checkboxes of rows that contains "filename1" I am using following code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(website_URL) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'filename1')]]/input").click()
```

How can I check the checkboxes where FileName='filename1'and Date='10/04/2019'?

Also,How can I uncheck the checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck the boxes the same way that you check them -- by clicking the `input` element.

The XPath locator you provided is a good one. To select other `input` elements underneath the `td`'s, you just need to change the text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'10/04/2019')]]/input").click()
```

To find the input with both, you can use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'filename1')] and td[contains(text(),'10/04/2019')]]/input").click()
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks,but I am not getting it correct when I use  ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[(contains(text(),'filename1')) and (contains(text(),'10/04/2019'))]]/input").click()```

Comment: You are looking for text in the same two `td` elements here, but `filename1` and `10/04/2019` are in separate `td` elements here. This would be the correct path to look for `tr` that has `td` elements with `filename1` and `10/04/2019`: `//tr[td[contains(text(),'filename1')] and td[contains(text(),'10/04/2019')]]/input`

Answer (score 2):

The below code will check and uncheck the checkboxes where FileName='filename1' and Date='10/04/2019'.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'10/04/2019')] and td[contains(text(),'filename1')] ]//input").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you posted is missing the `INPUT` that you want to click. Given your description of the table, I'm assuming it's inside the first `TD` in the row as I've shown below.

```
<tr class="class1">
  <td width="2%"> <input type="checkbox"> </td>   <!–– checkbox ––>
  <td width="2%"> 1 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 5 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 10/04/2019 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 12:05:45 </td>
  <td width="2%" style=word-wrap:break-word> xyz@gmail.com </td>
  <td width="2%"> filename1 </td>
</tr>
```

If this is the case, the XPath below will work

```
//tr[./td[.=' filename1 ']][./td[.=' 10/04/2019 ']]/td/input
```

If you plan to reuse this locator with other filenames and dates, I would insert variables into the locator. There are [many, many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962966/2386774) to insert a variable into a string using python. If you are using python 3.6, you can use the [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) below, as an example.

```
//tr[./td[.=' {filename} ']][./td[.=' {date} ']]/td/input
```

Now you can create a method and pass in the filename and date and return the correct `INPUT` easily.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this?
$x('//tr[td[contains(text(),"filename1")] and td[contains(text(),"10/04/2019")]]')
Sorry, I misunderstood. I updated the answer.