# Passing variable and string to the label field

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import nbinom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data = web.get_data_yahoo('^GSPC', start, end)
data.plot(y='Close')
plt.title("newtitle " +start) <--- I want a string and pass a variable to the title
```

I want to be able to pass a variable and text at the same time in the label fields but for some reason i can pass either a variable or a string but not both. Is there anyway it is possible for me to be able to pass both?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
plt.title("newtitle{0}".format(start))
```

or

```
plt.title(f'newtitle{start}')
```