# Changing API Params with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for some guidance for my script. As you can see, I want to have user input enter the vehicle reg number. This would then need to sit in the end of the URL so user input can dictate which vehicle is called via the API.

```
import requests
import json
registration = str(input("What's your REG number? "))
url = "https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests/?registration=PJ66FKY"
payload = {}
headers = {
  'x-api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'visid_incap_1151098=RTIoGHIETUSrjaf5W7QCScxP2l4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAkfOLSmlzNbGFWSfE86hQh; nlbi_1151098=hrz6EkFnOlWdINdZsRy5CgAAAADwbuHnEYVAPG0gSttx0Nsd; incap_ses_869_1151098=w7M8LuMrFQob4OeqJlAPDM9R2l4AAAAAKnNYAG3p3JxlCSU27U1/Qw=='
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
#print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
print (json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Comment: What is the question, actually? Is it the one answered by @jonrsharpe?

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned in the comments, you can use python's f-string formatting

```
import requests
import json
reg_num = str(input("What's your REG number? "))
url = f"https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests/?registration={reg_num}"
payload = {}
headers = {
  'x-api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'visid_incap_1151098=RTIoGHIETUSrjaf5W7QCScxP2l4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAkfOLSmlzNbGFWSfE86hQh; nlbi_1151098=hrz6EkFnOlWdINdZsRy5CgAAAADwbuHnEYVAPG0gSttx0Nsd; incap_ses_869_1151098=w7M8LuMrFQob4OeqJlAPDM9R2l4AAAAAKnNYAG3p3JxlCSU27U1/Qw=='
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
#print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
print (json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The `reg_num` variable's value will be automatically while execution

Comment: If this *is* an answer, it's also covered on the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205190/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, you are right. I didn't see your comment!.

Comment: This was really useful and solved my problem - thanks everyone