# How to call an endpoint from the command line and pass an argument to the URL?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to use my localhost address as the URL. In my endpoint, I have a few different airport codes to get the temperature from a JSON string.

I can type in my browser `localhost:5555/temp/lax` and the output on that address is just the temperature in Fahrenheit.

I am trying to write a command-line client that will do something like this:

```
python temp.py sfo
```

And I will get the output of the temperature at SFO airport.

In the endpoint program, I have my route as:

```
@app.route('/temp/<airportcode>')
```

In my mediocre command line client I can get the temperature to print out when I specify exactly what airport I want to see the temp at.

This will work: `http://127.0.0.1:5555/temp/lax`

But if I try to use this:

```
t = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5555/temp/<airportcode>")
```

I get a swarm of bad requests.

I also tried `requests.get` but got the same result.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a string variable called `airportcode` into a string template?

Comment: Try `t = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:555/temp/{}".format(airportcode))`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string