# Getting back type error when trying to make user input calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a payroll calculator and I cant get the input values to multiply. I think I converted the code into int() correctly but when i try and multiply them into a different var, it shoots back a "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" on line 6. I would love some feed back as far as what seems to be the issue.

```
hours = input("Enter number of hours you work: ")
hours = int(hours)
rate = input('Enter how much you make per hour: ')
rate = int(rate)
pay = hours * rate
print('You make $' + pay + ' a day')
days = input('Enter how many days you work a week: ')
days = int(days)
week = pay * days
print('You make $' + week + ' per week!')
month = week * 4
print('You make $' + month + ' a month!')
year = month * 12
print('You make $' + year + ' a year!!' )
```

Comment: This should answer your question: [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on this line `print('You make $' + pay + ' a day')` is because `pay` is an `int` variable but it is being **concatenated** to string.
Either type cast pay to `str` in the print statement like that:

```
print('You make $' + str(pay) + ' a day')
```

Or you can use comma `,` instead of concatenation `+`.

```
print('You make $', pay, 'a day')
```

Note that this method will add a space around the variable, when printing.

#### Ideally

You should use formatting that python provides.
f-string formatting:

```
print(f'You make $ {pay} a day')
```

Using `.format`

```
print('You make ${} a day'.format(pay))
```