# How to use variable and string while opening a python file for reading?

Tags: python, variables, filepath

I am trying to open a json file to write, but i need to build the file path with combination of variable value + some string

What I tried:

```
  with open(r"c:\csv\{ip}+aws_get_tags.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(ec2_tags, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

this is erroring out at opening that line.

Can some one let me know what syntax i am missing

Comment: ```"c:\csv\{ip}+aws_get_tags.json".format(ip = <ip>)```.

Comment: You can use *format* strings: `f"{ip}"` etc where `ip` is a variable available in the scope.  (So just replace `r` with `f` ...). Also, try to use `os.path.join`.

Comment: Hi suhanth, thanks for solution but that. <ip> in format is that manual entry ?, actually ip is variable which will pass into this script .any way let me try

Comment: @asp, it's just a illustration replace ``<ip>`` with the varaible or you can use one recommened by @Nishant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Comment: Nishant Sushanth thnaks for inputs putting 'f' solved the issue