# How can I add variable at end of write function and place it loop

Tags: python, for-loop, telnet

Im using telnetlib.Telnet function to connect to telnet devices but I can't figure out how to add variable at end of write function, I saw [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string) bu that did not helped me, so here is my code

```
def h4ck_th3_w0rld(HOST):
    user = 'admin'
    password = 'password'
    tn = None
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 23, 11)
 
        tn.read_until("Username: ", 7)
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("Password: ", 7)
            tn.write(password + "\n")

    for i in range(100, 256):
        for j in range(7, 7):
            ip_addressa = '192.168.%d.%d' % (j, i)
            h4ck_th3_w0rld(ip_addressa)
            print(ip_addressa)

    tn.write("cd /var/tmp\n")
    tn.write("./busybox telnet {}\n"(ip_addressa)) <--- here add ip_addressa variable
        tn.write("exit\n")
```

I need to put `/var/tmp/busybox telnet 172.24.%d.%d` in side while loop and request to looks like this

```
./busybox telnet 192.168.7.100
./busybox telnet 192.168.7.101
```

Comment: Do it the same way you did it to put `j` and `i` in `ip_addressa`

Comment: You obviously know how to format strings with variables, why do you think this is any different?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate it:

```py
tn.write("./busybox telnet " + ip_addressa + "\n")
```

or use `format()`:

```py
tn.write("./busybox telnet {}\n".format(ip_addressa))
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ip_addressa' referenced before assignment
None