# Compile Latex files from Python using a string within a loop

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex, os.system

I am creating a large set of math tests with question that have random numbers generated and I want to be able to save multiple copies, push them to latex and get them saved all within one python code. I understand the python os.system command and the subprocess.run command can do this, but I am not able to figure out how to get the file into the command because it iterates. I currently am trying to use a string to accomplish this task.

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    f = open("test_" + str(i).zfill(2) + ".tex", 'w+')
    ##### run test building code here ######
    f.close()
    #subprocess.run("pdflatex f.name")  #<--- How do I get this to run for each of the 10 files
```

I can run this with the actual file name, so I know it's not hard, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass in the string file name.

Answer (score 0):

Build the name beforehand, use an f-string to pass it in (assuming you're using Python 3.6+, otherwise see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)). Note that the `f` in front of the string has nothing to do with the file `f`.

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    file_path = "test_" + str(i).zfill(2) + ".tex"
    f = open(file_path , 'w+')
    #####
    f.close()
    subprocess.run(f"pdflatex {file_path}")
```