# How to replace string that contains curly bracket in Python?

Tags: python, string

Please see below code to understand my problem:

```
str_line = data['line']  # data['line'] holds "I was born in {year}"
str_year = '1987'
```

Expected output: `I was born in 1987`

```
print(str_line)
```

I have tried using following methods but the output always the original `str_line` (i.e., `I was born in {year}`).

```
str_line = str_line.replace('{{year}}',str_year)
```

and

```
str_line = str_line.replace('/{year/}',str_year)
```

Comment: You have only single braces, and you try to replace a string within double braces. Use `str_line = str_line.replace('{year}',str_year)`

Comment: if you are using user input for str_line, use string.replace, but If you just want to make code easier to read, use an f-string `str_line = f"I was born in {str_year}"`

Comment: Why do you even use `replace` and not `format`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Comment: You should use `str_line.format(year=str_year)`.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 , it's solved using   str_line.format(year=str_year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with `year` argument set to `str_year`:

```py
str_line = "I was born in {year}"
str_year = '1987'
print( str_line.format(year=str_year) )
# => I was born in 1987
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/uOtUub)

Documentation says

> ```
> str.format(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces `{}`. **Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument**. Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument.