# How do you fix the missing comma syntax warning in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, syntax-error

This is my code:

```
elif command == "3.1":
             os.system("cls")
             conn.send(command.encode())
             boxtitle = input("Please enter the title of the message : ")          
             print("[16] - Critical")
             print("[32] - Question")
             print("[48] - Warning")
             print("[64] - Info")
             boxerro = input("Please enter Error Type: ")
             box = input("Please enter the message you would like to write  : ")
             reading_file = open("errors.vbs", "r")

             new_file_content = ""
             for line in reading_file:
                 stripped_line = line.strip()
                 new_line = stripped_line.replace("x=msgbox(, 0+, )", "x=msgbox"(box, "0+", boxerro, boxtitle))
                 new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
             reading_file.close()

             writing_file = open("errors.vbs", "w")
             writing_file.write(new_file_content)
             writing_file.close()
```

What I'm trying to do here is when the command 3.1 is called it clears the cmd window sends this over to my client file and then it runs through what would you like I only get to the error on `new_line = stripped_line.replace("x=msgbox(, 0+, )", "x=msgbox"(box, "0+", boxerro, boxtitle))` What I'm doing here is its opening errors.vbs replacing what I have with what I want and closing it but I get the error

```
new_line = stripped_line.replace("x=msgbox(, 0+, )", "x=msgbox"(box, "0+", boxerro, boxtitle))
SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
```

But When I checked I couldn't see if I missed an error I'm really not sure how to fix these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Comment: See the color on the code, you can see the string parts, and the variable parts, you see that you don't replace by one string, that's the problem

Comment: This, here: `"x=msgbox"(box, "0+", boxerro, boxtitle)`—what is that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 il give it a try

Comment: This line is an error `new_line = stripped_line.replace("x=msgbox(, 0+, )", "x=msgbox"(box, "0+", boxerro, boxtitle))`. You have the to replace string incorrectly setup.

Comment: I recommend that you use a variable like `replace_str` and assign the value to it. Then use it in the line.replace string