# how to add dataframe columns based on value of loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, import

I have a dataframe in python, called df. It contains two variables, Name and Age. I want to do a loop in python to generate 10 new column dataframes, called Age_1, Age_2, Age_3....Age_10 which contain the values of Age.

So far I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
for i in range(1,11):
     df[Age_'i'] = df['Age']
```

Comment: `df[f'Age_{i}'] = `: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string. But are you really just looking to repeat that column 10 times?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this `for loop`:

```
for x in range(0,11):
    df['Age_'+str(x)]=df['Age']
```

**OR**

```
for x in range(0,11):
    df['Age_{}'.format(x)]=df['Age']
```

**OR**

```
for x in range(0,11):
    df['Age_%s'%(x)]=df['Age']
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.assign` and `**` unpacking.

```
df.assign(**{f'Age_{i}' : df['Age'] for i in range(11)})
```

[image]